# What are the most upvoted/downvoted questions and answers on the sites?

Tags: discussion, statistics, score

What are the most downvoted questions and answers on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Meta, and Super User history to date?

Similarly, what are the most upvoted questions and answers on SO, SF, Meta, and SU to date?

Comment: @Kirsh: Oh, boy!  We can have our own award show: the Stackys.  Awards include Best SuperUser Question, Best Supporting Comment,  Best Answer (Adapted Blog Post), and Best Foreign Language Question (which you're obvious gunning for).

Comment: @Pesto: Don't forget the "Best abuse of the phrase "As a programmer..."" award.

Comment: @Kirsh: Is that like a metaphysical question on the nature of the hero of the Zelda games?  "What is Link, if not a manifestation of man's desire to impose order and justice upon a universe that is anything but?"

Comment: And the prize will be a Tony!

Comment: No idea why it's closed. Valid request for statistics.

Comment: True @Pat - but if reopened, the delete vote won't be relevant anymore. :)

Comment: The most negative voted question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384565/return-json-object-with-duplicate-keys-using-c-sharp

Comment: Anyone else notice that @B.Balamanigandan 's post for the most downvoted question was *his own question*?

Comment: Always make the best out of your mistakes @applemonkey496 haha

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this became archive for bad questions, and I don't think that's a proper goal. So better close it, keep what we have already, and move on.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon/84629#84629) *was* the highest up voted answer in history ... then [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)... and now its [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902).

For all others, [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1437/most-upvoted-answers) is the comprehensive list ([previously deleted post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150529134532/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)). [Here's the list](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1438/most-upvoted-questions) for questions.

<sup>Disclaimer: These have the most **up votes**, and may not be the highest scoring. There is a difference.</sup>

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20101008061929/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164432/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you/164556) *was* the most down voted answer in history. Notice it has a **ton** of up votes.  Now it's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/871405/why-do-i-need-an-ioc-container-as-opposed-to-straightforward-di-code/871420#871420) - with far fewer up-votes (but still more up than down...)
For all others, [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1439/most-down-voted-answers) is the comprehensive list.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly) is the most down-voted question, and [here's the list](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1440/most-down-voted-questions) for questions.

<sup>Disclaimer: These have the most **down votes**, and may not be the lowest scoring. There is a difference.</sup>

---

As for the scores (June 3, 15):

The lowest-scoring question is [Don't close questions where the user has requested that it not be closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed) (MSE, -157), the lowest-scoring answer is [Info: Contacted by spammers (Ispirer Systems) referencing Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/info-contacted-by-spammers-ispirer-systems-referencing-stack-overflow/274959#274959) (MSO, -269).

The highest-scoring question is [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) (SO; +11,226), the highest-scoring answer is [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902) (SO; +16,359) (the answer to the above question).

Comment: Couldn't you use your sandbox powers to find the ones with the highest and lowest scores by comparing the ups against the downs?

Comment: There's an actual "score" column...

Comment: Yes, I can easily find 'score', but the question was directed at up votes and down votes, not the highest scoring questions.

Comment: FWIW... lowest-scoring question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566010
lowest-scoring answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182845

Comment: THE SANDBOX RETURNS <3

Comment: (the highest-scoring Q&A are still the cartoon Q&A, so less interesting...) (yeah - folks really hate non-programming-questions)

Comment: I don't know why still we are keeping that question in SO , Because those questions are not a programming question

Comment: @Kirsh: because enough people want it to keep re-opening it...

Comment: @Ian: your link to most downvoted question of all time points to an answer, not a question.  (my answer, in fact!)  are you saying that the answer is the most downvoted item in history, or is the link just supposed to go to the question?

Comment: Actually, now that I look at your queries, it is in fact my answer (not the question).  The reason is that, for quite a while, it was being heavily downvoted to keep it at exactly 256 votes.

Comment: Yeah they point to answers/questions. I suppose I could change them to only questions but I never felt the need, false advertising!

Comment: hmmm this is missing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I'm getting a lot of 403's on the links. I was curious...

Comment: Any chance this can be updated?  Other questions are pointing here now, but since the best links in this answer are dead, not sure we'll see a current answer added.  See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54396/

Comment: Can we update the dead links?

Comment: Was rep ever awarded to the OP and answerers to any of these? If so, has it since been removed?

Comment: Can you either update this or make it CW so that other people can? I tried to but it [was rejected](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13848)

Comment: Actually the highest voted answer is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)

Comment: @Lucky You added the wrong link, didn't you? I changed it.

Comment: @nicael yes but now the second link of the answer has got lesser upvotes(4428) than the link i mentioned(4766)..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely/2003515#2003515..so i think that link should be updated as well..

Comment: the first link on the most downvoted answer in history link is missing..

Comment: And, this question now has more than 157 downvotes: [A New Code License: The MIT, this time with Attribution Required](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272956)

Comment: See archive.org for dead links: https://web.archive.org/web/20150529005812/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books

Comment: what about this http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509

Comment: The top-questions list just proves that [Git is too damn hard](http://merrigrove.blogspot.com/2014/02/why-heck-is-git-so-hard-places-model-ok.html)

Comment: Wow, Git sure is well represented in that list. :)

Answer (score 31):

*[Official FAQ on gender pronouns and Code of Conduct changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes/334934)* was one of the most downvoted questions on the whole site, sitting at -1285 5 days after posting. OP has gone from 1924 to currently 342 points:

[image]

It has since been deleted by the author. An archived version can be found [here on the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20191022115257/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes).

---

### Update:

*[An Update to our Community and an Apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology)* is sitting at -1996 as of 2019-09-26 23:30 UTC-05:00.

Before it was deleted on 2019-12-23, it was voted to -2264. An archived version from just before deletion can again be found [on the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20191223172246/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology)

Comment: Just an FYI: You can search for posts by score. For example, a [search for `score:..-300`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=score%3a..-300). However, that's on the net score, not upvotes and downvotes separately.

Comment: Evidence of the Gender pronouns failure has been deleted.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Yes, the link to the archived version is in the answer also.

Answer (score 11):

[Surprised that none posted Jeff's answers on meta.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53297/161537)

[Yes the creator of meta has the (one of the) most downvoted answer!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33949/161537) :)

That includes two down-votes from me as well.. :)

Comment: This should be inspiring haha

Comment: I also downvoted. :-D

Answer (score 6):

The top upvoted questions on SO:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes

The top view questions on SO:

> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A250

Answer (score 2):

The lowest voted answer in the past 30 days is [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072903/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-invert-a-stack-without-using-anyother-extra-data-s) at -17. To go back farther you would have to consult the data dumps that are made publicly available.

**Edit**: I was also able to find [This One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576136/how-can-i-convince-a-professor-to-move-from-java-to-c-on-his-teaching-and-resear) currently at -21.

Comment: I am asking about all from past history .. not Like past 30 days

Comment: I just told you to go back further you need to consult the data dumps.

Comment: TXI ... You are wrong, it is now -18.... well, -19 after I saw it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I recall seeing one at close to -30. Are deleted questions included in the data dump?

Comment: mmyers: I would imagine they are, since deleted questions are not actually deleted from the system (10k people can still see them, afterall? Unless they are routinely wiped from the system after a while).

Comment: Chacha...what part of "currently" are you not understanding? It is entirely feasible that the voting will change once more attention is brought to it.

Comment: If you add ![currently] in markup then whatever you post will automagically be updated to reflect any changes

Comment: Somebody - not the OP - deleted the one at -21 :(

Answer (score 2):

This [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story) on Meta StackOverflow has -2064 downvotes; and rightfully so. I really hope they keep developer story :(

**Edit:**

Just noticed that the links on other answers on this question aren't working, so I'm just gonna screenshot it so we can remember this moment:
[image: -2064 Stackoverflow Meta Question]

Answer (score 1):

Beside the SEDE, there is also the top search bar, which is very useful and smart. It should be used with the SEDE, not instead of it. It is very useful to read its [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) once, it might help a lot later.

Your 3 main ways to search something are:

1. SEDE
2. search bar
3. Google

All of them have its advantages and disadvantages, use always the tool most feasible for your problem.

On the search bar, you can find the most upvoted/downvoted question/answer on this way:

1. enter `is:question` or `is:answer` in the search box
2. sort the output by votes
3. If you want the most upvoted post, then you already see it. If you want the lowest voted post, go to the last page.

There are also far more sophisticated options, too, for example with `favorite:mine [linux] created:2d..` you can see the `[linux]` questions younger than 2 days in your favorites.

Comment: This worked for me. I found the question I mentioned in my answer at the bottom of the last page, verifying it as the lowest on Meta SE. This is actually, IMO, the best answer, because it moves beyond the need for "this is the current record" answers like I gave! Now we can all see for ourselves in real time!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an incredibly low-scoring question right here on Meta with an overall score of -361 - and it has a bounty on it worth 100 reputation at the moment!

[We're testing advertisements across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329763/were-testing-advertisements-across-the-network)

With an overall loss of 122 reputation from this, I can figure its overall up- and downvotes as follows: a pure -361 with no upvotes would lose 722, then each up- and downvote pair from there to keep the score at -361 would add 3 reputation (a question upvote is +5; a downvote -2.) This would be 200 upvotes (and additional downvotes) to gain 600 reputation overall to lighten the overall loss to 122. So, at the moment, it should have 200 upvotes and 561 downvotes.