# What's the most downvoted question or answer on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, down-votes, humor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most upvoted/downvoted questions and answers on the sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/what-are-the-most-upvoted-downvoted-questions-and-answers-on-the-sites)

After watching the meltdown which just happened on SO question [Can you explain what this code fragment is doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296135/can-you-explain-what-this-code-fragment-is-doing), I've got to wonder what was the most down voted question on StackOverflow?

Comment: Hopefully, it won't be this one.  ;-)

Comment: Duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/what-are-the-most-upvoted-downvoted-questions-and-answers-on-the-sites

Comment: The question would be the one about Microsoft solving the halting problem.

Comment: Sweet, my second opportunity to use my new closing powers!

Comment: I can't believe a Q this stupid has already been asked.  ;-)

Comment: @jjnguy - Mine is more powerful then yours :)

Comment: I have never met anybody so angry at the ternary operator as that guy. It apparently broke into his house and clubbed his puppy to death.

Comment: "Ternary" is just the criminal alias that "conditional" uses for the purpose of canine slaughter.

Comment: This question has an answer with -93
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766785/fixing-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-for-a-stuck-my/16861630#16861630