# What is the most downvoted post on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What are the most upvoted/downvoted questions and answers on the sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/what-are-the-most-upvoted-downvoted-questions-and-answers-on-the-sites)
>   [What’s the most downvoted question or answer on StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15246/whats-the-most-downvoted-question-or-answer-on-stackoverflow)

A while back, I posted an answer that was being totally misinterpreted by everyone and of course, perhaps, I didn't do the best job of clarifying myself and/or I was in fact just totally, completely and utterly wrong.  Anyway, within a short period of time, it received like 20 downvotes, I then deleted it.

What is the most downvoted post on Stackoverflow? (Should these posts remain?)

Comment: I think it is the one by Sara Chipps about Monica that got 1300+ downvotes.

Comment: Who would downvote this question? Can we see the downvotes over time? I would bet the slope is negative and geometric

Comment: This post probably is the most downvoted.

Comment: ...*```**iorny**```*...

Answer (score 12):

- <strike>48</strike> 56 downvotes - question:
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156363/create-a-compiler-for-windows
- <strike>43</strike> 45 downvotes - answer:
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174892/what-is-the-most-spectacular-way-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-with-c/174901#174901

Comment: Nathan is the man! It's well worth looking at some of his other questions.

Comment: Ouch, guess I got off easy!

Comment: Update:  (8 mins after you posted this) It is now -51

Comment: @ 9 mins:  Now -52

Comment: It is now -53..

Comment: Is -100 a possibility?

Comment: @bobobobo - thanks for volunteering for the job of keeping this answer up-to-date.  Glad to know you're on it. ;-)

Comment: I missed the first series/season of 'Nathan shoots for the moon' what is the compiler called, and when was the OS finished?  Did Jack Bauer shoot him in the final hour?

Comment: @tvanfosson I am TOTALLY on it..

Comment: The first URL now redirects to a +705/-5 question.

Comment: It's -217 here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly

Answer (score 0):

I thought I saw a net; -100 on meta the other day, but I can't find it.

Remain impressed that [Evan Carroll](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135854) manages to get nett downvotes on over 80% of his answers on meta - there is a Machiavellian plan at work there, I'm sure.

According to [What are the most upvoted/downvoted questions and answers on the sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/what-are-the-most-upvoted-downvoted-questions-and-answers-on-the-sites) the most downvoted question in SO history is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164432/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you/164556#164556 - which despite a ton of downvotes remains net <strike>+341</strike> +1055!

Comment: I do believe that Evan's questions and answers are intended to illicit downvotes. I am convinced that no one could be serious and act the way he does.

Comment: @snicker - I reckon its a plan - he's negative gaming to try to find a zero day exploit that will suddenly give him a 10K account, at which point he can take over the world ... I need some fresh air.

Comment: sounds plausible.

Comment: @snicker: you don't illicit downvotes, you elicit them. Unless the downvotes are immoral in some way.

Comment: @snicker: unfortunately you are incorrect; he's somewhat infamous in Perl circles for the same behaviour.

Comment: How about a net -1825 here ; ) https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248