# Most Downvoted Question/ Answer

Tags: discussion, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most upvoted/downvoted questions and answers on the sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/what-are-the-most-upvoted-downvoted-questions-and-answers-on-the-sites)

I think it would be interesting to see which question/answer is the most downvoted one, without referring to the monthly data dump.

Any idea how to get this?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/what-are-the-most-upvoted-downvoted-questions-and-answers-on-the-sites

Answer (score 2):

The most downvoted question is simple. Just click questions, sort by votes and goto the last page.

Currently its [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357811/vim-vs-emacs-final-battle-closed) And the most voted none closed question is [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072903/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-invert-a-stack-without-using-anyother-extra-data-s).

How to get the answers is something you can't see simply. You can see past 30 days in the 10k tools. Currently it's [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568144/how-can-i-convince-a-client-that-audio-on-a-website-is-a-bad-idea/1568194#1568194)

Comment: Most downvoted answer: I thought is this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871405/why-do-i-need-an-ioc-container-as-opposed-to-straightforward-di-code/871420#871420

Comment: Like I said in the answer, you can only search in the 10k tools for most downvoted in the past 30 days, and according to that list, it was the one i linked to. Yours is older than 30 days.

Comment: there's a difference between "most downvoted" and "lowest net score"