# What's your most unexpectedly upvoted question/answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, voting

I think most of us have seen it. You post something innocuous, it receives an upvote, then another, then another, and before you know it you've got another handful of badges pinned onto your chest.

Now I know that rep shouldn't matter and all that, but I also know that I'm only human. I do have a certain feeling about the quality of a question or answer that I post, and certain (subconscious) expectations about the number of votes it will receive. And sometimes it just happens that the actual number is very different.

What question or answer have you posted, that unexpectedly received way more upvotes (or downvotes) than you had expected?

Comment: Almost any question voted up on Sundays:(

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a list question which is asking people to respond with effectively semi-random questions or answers which they *personally* found to match the criteria in the question. There's no possibility of actually having an authoritative or "correct" answer, nor does it actually ask for discussion about the site or the software which powers the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely [my answer to "Hello world in less than 20 bytes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284797/hello-world-in-less-than-20-bytes/284898#284898).

It's an entirely frivolous answer, but has 424 upvotes and 58 downvotes. It's almost certainly my most downvoted answer as well as my most upvoted one :)

The fact that [a picture of me in a dressing gown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140376/what-easter-eggs-have-you-placed-in-code/140507#140507) (with accompanying story, admittedly) is worth 291 upvotes (and *no* downvotes) on SO is surprising too.

On Meta it's even sillier: 108 upvotes and two downvotes for posting [my daily timetable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/555/why-does-jon-skeet-never-sleep/566#566).

Comment: On Meta, though, it's not as surprising, I think :] (And also, the "SO presence" in it is quite impressive, I have to admit) (Or something to be concerned about)

Comment: @jon I took half a day on a sunday to read that question....

Comment: All three posts were removed.

Comment: All three links are dead now. Please delete the answer.

Comment: The answer was deleted on 2011-08-31.

Answer (score 2):

Easily [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148857/what-is-the-opposite-of-parse/148866#148866)  to *What is the opposite of ‘parse’?*.

After that, it would have to be one of my rants on securing your .NET code. (Hint: don't waste your time on it.)

Comment: All of your code-obfuscation/copy-protection rants were A+++.

Answer (score 2):

It's a toss-up between:

- [What does "<<" mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493517/what-does-mean-in-c/2493526#2493526) (apparently people are *really* interested in the bitshift operators - almost got me a guru badge)
- [How should I ethically approach user password storage for later plaintext retrieval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283937/how-should-i-ethically-approach-user-password-storage-for-later-plaintext-retriev/2290037#2290037) (notable in the sense of being a "don't do this" answer of the sort that people often complain about... basically a rant, even if a well-written one.  It's one of my most-upvoted *and* most-downvoted answers on SO).

There's also:

- [How to deal with programmers who refuse to indent their code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275349/how-to-deal-with-with-programmers-who-refuse-to-indent-their-code/2277693#2277693) (I added a *late*, silly answer to what I thought was a silly question. Usually the only times I get votes for the off-the-cuff remarks are here on Meta!)

In some cases it's kind of an "escape velocity" thing - once you hit 10 upvotes, people resist giving you any more, but after you hit 20 or so, people start upvoting the answer *because* it's so popular).

Answer (score 1):

For me, that would have to be my [most upvoted answer](https://superuser.com/questions/29339/gmail-not-spam-vs-move-to-inbox/29340#29340).

I mean seriously, all I said was pure logic and guessing, and on a question which is moreover off-topic now on Super User. Really nothing to be proud of.

Comment: The accepted answer on that question is much better ;)

Comment: @Jon - yes, wonderful case of "WTF did this one get accepted", in my opinion. Note also that the original contained not only a signature, but the contact mail as well. Impressive.

Answer (score 1):

From the "Captain Obvious" archives comes this little gem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238610/secrets-for-burning-the-midnight-oil/238613#238613

Answer (score 1):

[Pick one.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3a2915%20subjective&tab=votes)

Although I think that my answer to [Is a GUID unique 100% of the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771/is-a-guid-unique-100-of-the-time/39776#39776) is most interesting for several reasons:

- Terribly easy to google
- If you understand what a GUID is, how MS generates one, and basic math, then you can easily figure it out yourself
- My answer is nothing more than a nicely formatted cut-n-paste from wikipedia
- It continues to get attention - apparently it's a true FAQ
- None of the other answers are really *wrong* - though I dislike saying "yes" to this question because technically it is *possible* for a collision to occur

But then there's always [How Can I Know Whether I Am a Good Programmer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378/how-can-i-know-whether-i-am-a-good-programmer/52412#52412) which was well answered by the time I got to it, I threw something together not expecting much to happen, and then found that people apparently thought it was a little more interesting than the existing answers - and continue to find it interesting.

Comment: I do feel a guilty pleasure in winning this particular e-peen contest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805/hello-world-what-did-your-first-ever-computer-program-do

Comment: You just made me upvote that last one :)

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised at the level of interest in my most-upvoted question: [Fastest way to determine if an integer’s square root is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer). At one point it got about 12k views in a single day. I [thought it was a bug](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/138526-possible-bug-12k-views-in-one-day-on-a-single-question), but it turned out the question had just made it to the front page of reddit.

There's also "What real life bad habits has programming given you?", which I answered with "[I now consider 256 to be a nice, round number](https://web.archive.org/web/20101008061929/http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions/164432/what-real-life-bad-habits-has-programming-given-you/164556#164556)". With 107 downvotes, this is [the most downvoted answer in the history of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/what-are-the-most-upvoted-downvoted-questions-and-answers-on-the-sites/11022#11022)! (For a while people were actively downvoting it to keep its net score at exactly 256 votes. It recently passed 1024 net votes.)

Answer (score 0):

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086445/obfuscation-and-gpl/1086455#1086455).

<sub><sub>And [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns).</sub></sub>