# What's the most negative score of any question ever asked on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most upvoted/downvoted questions and answers on the sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/what-are-the-most-upvoted-downvoted-questions-and-answers-on-the-sites)

... just wondering. Can anybody point me into the right direction?

Comment: You're so funny.

Comment: Technically, the *highest* negative integer is -1. Are you looking for the *lowest* negative number?

Comment: @Matt Damn. I came here just to say that.

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed as a duplicate, since the answer to the other question just has **broken** links...it no longer actually answers the question.

Comment: @Nick: I agree the content in the original question needs updating, but this question is still a duplicate of the first.

Comment: @Jon - True, but now neither has an answer, this one's locked and that one has an outdated/invalid accepted answer...so it's a bad place to point this one to.  Duplicates don't cover chronologically different questions though, what if the question was asked 10 years from now?  Would the old answers be valid?....no, the answer changes over time, so I'm not even sure it's a "duplicate", since some questions are time-sensitive.  E.g. think of SO, "what current bugs are in this API"...changes version to version, is it a duplicate? I think closing as a duplicate is ambiguous in these cases.

Comment: @Nick: We can still add new answers to the old question, or the answer authors can make updates. A comparison to the example question you gave isn't really valid, since an API would be versioned, so the same set of bugs would always apply to that version -- a new question would be asked about a newer version. In any event, I see where you're going with that line of reasoning. I agree that it's tough to keep up with these types of questions, but the purpose of closing as a duplicate is such that when someone asks the same *question* they should be redirected to a single repository of *answers*.

Comment: @Jon - I agree with the intent, but in this case for example, I think the likelihood of this getting answered since the other question has an accepted one is slim to none, unfortunately.  I'll add a comment to Jeff's answer over there and see if he can edit it a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you meant the lowest negative score, apparently this one, with a score of -38: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815931/missing-identifier-even-though-its-defined-on-the-line-above

How do I find it? Sort all questions by number of votes then go to the last page.

The question has been deleted; an archived version is available [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130520083253/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815931/haskell-missing-identifier-even-though-its-defined-one-line-above/15816093).

Comment: I see a score of 616 for that question with only 2 downvotes??

Comment: The mentioned question is deleted as duplicate, it has 0 up- or downvotes. The referred to question has 676 upvotes, 2 downvotes and 1389 favorites: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler. Maybe @Lie meant another question originally?

Comment: @Abel: fixed with the current latest most negative question; I'm not quite sure how the previous link got there.

Comment: True, and most negative answer currently on SO is http://stackoverflow.com/a/278879/447356, standing at -42 :)

Comment: Close, but I can do better ;)... -218 downvotes (and +71) on this question: [q/3905734](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734). But I cheated, I used [most-down-voted-questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36660/most-down-voted-questions) (it also shows questions that are closed or locked).

Answer (score 2):

Belongs on meta, but to answer your question, when you're on the "Questions" tab up there, you can sort for votes. Go to the last page.

Comment: That only shows questions that have not been deleted though. I would think that the question with the lowest score would be one that has been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, it's -69, but maybe that will change soon. :-P