# Vote for an old question

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

I've been using Stackoverflow for a while now, and I want to know if I should vote for an old question/answer that has been useful for me and has already 18 votes for example?

Comment: Questions like this baffle me. What would lead you to believe that might not be a good idea?

Comment: So, make it 19.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I just don't see the point on adding more votes for an answer that has already many votes, that's all. that's why i'm asking.

Comment: Here's a link to the question with the highest votes (4433 upvotes): http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11017/184933

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up - see second question - so yes!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is nothing to stop you from doing so, and it is actually encouraged.

If the question helped, give the asker some rep.

If the answer helped, give the answerer some rep.

Answer (score 16):

Absolutely, there isnt any time limit.

Good content should be timeless.

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely vote. That's the whole purpose of voting!

[image: Tooltips]