# Getting downvotes in bulk on different questions

Tags: feature-request, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

Suddenly, I noticed I am getting downvotes on my questions that were asked many months back!

And few days back my reputation was rolled back stating that someone has upvoted me! I would like to say, if this is the case, you should take a precautionary action like

1. If someone downvotes, he should give a mandatory comment on that. And if other accept the comment then the downvote should be done.
2. Same with the upvote.

Waiting for your response on this.

EDIT:

I changed my name and pic due to this down votes, now after a month, I restored my name and pic, and suddenly got 3 downvotes on some past question, see the image.

[image]

Comment: For others, here is his rep. tab. http://stackoverflow.com/users/1395941/anoop-vaidya?tab=reputation On Jan 10th a user was removed. Today (Jan 15th) he received 2 down votes, one on a closed question in december last year, another on a question asked in october last year.

Comment: I removed on question as not a suitable answer was there.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - If your question is suitable for the Site and you don't have suitable answer then removing the question does not make any sense. Instead, add bounty to get some attention and useful answer.

Comment: What would I do, if some one suddenly upvotes or downvotes me ?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - What do you mean my suddenly. Voting always happen suddenly.

Comment: @hims056 : when i posted the question no one downvoted, now today got downvotes on 3 of my questions in less than 2 minutes of time? Should I feel it as coincidence, that 3 persons from different corner searched my 3 questions out of 10, and hated it, downvoted it?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - If that is serial voting, it will be reversed automatically. If it doesn't reverses, and you think it is a serial voting, you can mail to `team@stackexchange.com`.

Comment: Related [What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28756)

Answer (score 5):

You are asking three points at once:

1. Downvotes on questions that were asked many months back
2. Rollback of points
3. Proposal: Force comments on downvotes

Answers

1. By design old questions can be found and voted even if they are years old. Also see [Vote for an old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133204/vote-for-an-old-question)
2. See [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it)
3. Duplicate of [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

Comment: Please see my updated question with image attached.