# Why can't I undo my vote to close?

Tags: feature-request, voting, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

Why? Sometimes, upon reflection, one decides that a topic SHOULD stay open. Why can't we undo our close vote?

Comment: The only solution is to wait until the question is closed and then vote to reopen.

Comment: This has already been thoroughly covered - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes

Comment: Close votes will also expire after a certain amount of time, so if the close votes never reach the threshold of 5, they will eventually fade away.

Comment: @I'm kind of a big deal - I was wondering whether that was the case. I'd voted to close a question here on meta (before realising I should flag it) and a while later I saw that it hadn't been closed but the vote had disappeared.

Comment: @ChrisF: The few times I've noticed it happen I wasn't able to figure out exactly how long it took for them to expire. However, after it expires you can actually vote to close again (i.e. your "one vote" only counts if the question actually closes).