# Length of time before reconsidering feature requests

Tags: discussion, feature-request

So there's a feature request (I'm not the OP) which has recently been tagged `status-declined`.  I was/am highly in favor of the request.  Now I'm depressed.  I will probably drown my sorrows tonight in a case of dark English ale (nothing like the old world).

This particular feature-request had 72 upvotes on it and the reason given for declining was not all that great (IMHO).  How long do we wait (realistically) before asking for a highly-popular feature request which was declined to be reconsidered?

(ok, to save you some forensic time the feature in question is [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes), but this is really just in general)

Comment: The original request, though, doesn't have a very strong argument for it.  The question either belongs or does not belong.  If wording can be changed to make it belong, then a new question is probably the better choice, rather than trying to save one in the throes of death.  Further, you shouldn't be closing questions that are only a slight wording change away from being a good question on SO.  If they change it significantly enough to make it reasonable for SO, then it's really a vastly different question than the one you closed.

Comment: Also, I recommend drowning your sorrows in waffles.  Doesn't have the nasty next-morning effects your choice includes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with you on the slight wording change thing but am more thinking about the screw-up when I misread a valid question.

Comment: I've long been convinced that we need to introduce full contact moderating on SO.  In fact...

Comment: Waffles are actually my cure for tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 2):

"Furthermore, it is my opinion that Carthage must be destroyed." - *Cato, the Elder*

Nag, nag, nag, nag. That helps. If you really want it, piss Jeff off with it.

The "bug" that you could circumvent the 15-chars-limit in comments with spaces wasn't that a big deal. But people complained and complained about it. Jeff got fed up and sacrificed valuable programming time to "fix" this. Follow that example!

Now go and write your dupe. I am out of close votes. Now or never.

<sub>You also could add an answer to the linked question, to restart the discussion (and also get a Necromancer badge maybe). It would be the correct, but less nagging thing to do.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can repost it immediately, or wait as long as you like.

However, unless you present a new argument for the feature, or ask for a slightly different version of the feature it's likely to be closed as a dupe, and if not it'll be declined again anyway.

If you want to ask for the same exact feature that was explicitly declined, there's no real time period to wait, but I probably would wait 6-12 months at least.

Comment: And not even in that case. I've seen just barely related questions marked as duplicate. People just don't seem to note the variations.

Comment: I know it can get reposted immediately, but there's the "realistic" part that I'd like to get a better gauge on.  Good point on rewording.