# Provide (optional) anonymous reasoning field for down-votes

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Leaving an anonymous comment when voting.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/leaving-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting)

Extending the ["Please consider adding a comment..." reminder](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes/2373#2373) with a comment field bellow which allows to leave an *anonymous* comment reasoning the down-vote. This could help preventing revenge-down-votes and yet help the OP improving.

The field should be clarifying the optionality of this process, but as a motivation, half the down-vote-cost could be refunded as a reward. Or only half the down-vote loss for the OP is cast for unreasoned down-votes.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50030/canned-reasons-for-up-down-vote-w-example-of-how-it-would-work

Comment: I think this has been suggested and [status-declined] before, can't find it though.

Comment: Picked from the "related" list: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/leaving-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting

FWIW, I'm against it. Stop connecting votes and comments - that's why we have the "revenge" problem to begin with! If you have something to say, leave a comment *regardless* of whether or not you vote, and don't feel you need to state the obvious every time you down-vote a half-assed attempt at asking/answering.

Comment: This question is a clear duplicate of [6521](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/leaving-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting), however IMO 6521 should *not* have been closed as a duplicate of [135](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes). If Ivo is reading this, then we can resurrect 6521.

Comment: 6521 is now open again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding an **anonymous** comment is a great idea, as long as it is **optional**.

p.s.  I have no idea why people are closing since the duplicate is pretty different here.

**EDIT:**  I see from one of the other links posted, why people are calling it a duplicate, but please notice that that question was mistakenly closed as a duplicate, so it got no traction.  I think it would be easier to leave this question open, than to resurrect the other one.

Comment: I'll just reopen it (so they can close it again), but indeed this is a 'new' request if you ask me

Comment: @Lance: *how* is the duplicate different?

Comment: The idea of making down-vote comments was raised in one of the answers to my question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes/3733#3733

Comment: @Shog9, the duplicate is about having specific canned answers, while this one is about a comment field that __can__ be filled out, and it posts that comment anonymously.  It's definitely a different approach than the other.

Comment: @Shog9, after looking at the other links (after the first one), I see what people mean by duplicate, though unfortunately that one was __mistakenly__ closed as a duplicate.  It'd be easier to leave this one up, than try to ressurect that one.

Comment: For the record, I linked the canned responses one not to call this a duplicate of it, but to cite it as a related avenue of thought.

Comment: @Lance: It may be easier, but that isn't really fair to the two people who answered the original...

Comment: @Shog9, this sounds like an ideal candidate for merging.  (If you do that, please don't feel you need to merge my answer, it doesn't have any important information).