# I want my baby back bounty or my bounty back baby

Tags: discussion, bounties, expired-bounty

So I put a bounty on something. Then I figured it out. Can I just wait the next 7 days for it to expire and then get my points back? Is there any way to salvage them? Please, people, I'm desperate for SO fame and fortune.

Comment: It's not refundable.

Comment: Nope, bounties are advertisements and are non-refundable.

Comment: So why all the down votes?

Comment: *I'm desperate for SO fame and fortune.* - Try not to spoil it by asking questions in this manner. I really doubt if adding *baby* or *desperate for SO fame and fortune* will leave a good impression about you.

Comment: See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: @R.J. So sense of humor is not appreciated, understood.

Comment: @dave We appreciate humor, but only when it's good (which means different things to different people).

Comment: I guess you didn't know [we hate fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Comment: I see what you did there, @Yannis

Comment: Your "humor" did not make me laugh.

Comment: So, I'm stupid and not funny... anything else anyone wants to add to the list?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that, @dave.

Comment: Joking aside - the jocular tone of the question truly detracts from its meaning and what you are trying to convey. In this sense, it is noise - people have commented about the post, not the person. No one is saying that you are stupid or unfunny (we don't know you, so how could we tell?), just that in this context, the joking wasn't helping to get your point across.

Comment: @Oded, I think the reason for the downvotes was primarily due to that fact that I tagged the question as 'bug' and not as 'discussion'. I can see why many would infer that I believe there is a problem with the bounty system because of the 'bug' tag, but in reality I don't believe there is, just needed clarification. A kind 'RTFM' is what I suppose I received from you and others. There seems to be no reason to downvote humor (or even poor humor, as expressed by many), especially after reading the voting the rules MSO.

Comment: @dave - I can't speak for others and I have no idea why people have downvoted the question. Lack of research is certainly one reason people downvote on Meta (and Meta tends to be downvote heavy in this regard).

Comment: Every user absolutely cannot be expected to read all of the documentation about SO and retain all behavioral rules. Why not have a finite selection of possible reasons for downvoting on questions. This way the user will know why they're being downvoted and learn. Instead of perceived blind punishment.

Comment: Alas people are specifically allowed to vote as they see fit so this is not possible.  Often (as in this case) someone comments to explain why. Revenge downvotes are one reason this does not happen always

Comment: You would eliminate the possibility of revenge votes if you made people specify a reason for down-voting with checkboxes or radio buttons.

Comment: You may be intersted in supporting this: [anonymous comment with a downvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60877/proposed-solution-to-the-downvote-out-of-spite-problem-allow-one-anonymous-comm) with regards to the radio buttons; I thought that was already a proposal but I can't find it. I may create some mockup and post that as a feature request (unless you'd like to do it); I would only support this is there was an "other/rather not say" option

Comment: @RichardTingle you seem to have clout and influence in this community. You would probably be taken seriously if you proposed it.

Comment: @dave Ha, we are scrupulously fair here. My [most recent suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207366/automatic-bounties-on-heavily-upvoted-unanswered-questions) got -7, regardless, [here is the proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208030/allow-anonymous-feedback-on-a-downvote-to-be-given-through-radio-buttons)

Comment: @dave If you look back in the history, sorted by votes, you can see some questions by some *very well respected* people here being heavily down voted.

Comment: @RichardTingle, If we were truly fair, in the same way that your question is linked directly to your identity, your down vote should be as well. When you down voted, the question you down voted, why you down voted, who you down voted. If the goal is accuracy of information while following community policy, reasoning behind down voting is just as helpful as reasoning an answer.

Comment: @dave: You didn't have to have read every piece of documentation: If you'd searched on Meta for [bounty refund](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=bounty+refund), or [get bounty back](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+bounty+back), you'd have found many exact duplicates.

Comment: @dave What you are talking about is a completely different issue. There are *countless* requests for that here. If you wish to talk about that, look for one of those. But you should **not** expect a good reception for such a proposal.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Are you insinuating all duplicate questions deserve down voting?

Comment: This discussion might be a bit easier if you don't go jumping to extreme conclusions just for the sake of argument, dave. I saw no such insinuation in @DavidRobinson's comment. That said, I *do* often find myself down voting certain kinds of duplicates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bounty is like placing an ad - you pay money to get more eyeballs on your question.

It doesn't guarantee you will get an answer or that any answers you do get will be of any help.

Like paying for an ad, you don't get money back if it didn't work as you expected.

Reading about [how the bounty system works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) would have told you all this.

Comment: Just a small doubt. Why would you provide an answer to a question which is a certain duplicate? You are a diamond symbol guy, so can't you just directly close the question marking it as a duplicate?!

Comment: Wow, you guys really do eat each other alive

Comment: @dave - yeah. Thankfully, my diamond is fire retardant.

Comment: @R.J. in my opinion a specific answer to the actual question plus close as duplicate of a more general question that contains the answer amongst other things is by far the most helpful outcome

Comment: @R.J - consider that the duplicate has quite a lot of information and the OP would have to dig through it all before finding the answer (if they even read that long), giving them a direct response with a link to more information is a better option, no?

Comment: Yeah that sounds good. I just wanted to know,  because you already have the powers to do so. :-P