# Allow anonymous feedback on a downvote to be given through radio buttons

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

## Introduction

Often people who receive down votes are uncertain *why* they are receiving them. This is in part because those giving the down votes do not wish to comment publicly for fear of revenge down voting (and the general social stigma of publicly saying "This sucks because" <sup>1</sup>) and also because writing comments takes time. Therefore I propose<sup>2</sup> radio buttons to select from a number of common reasons for down voting.

## Related proposals

A related solution; [anonymous comments on down voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/allow-users-to-leave-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting) also sets out to solve this problem, however that does not solve the effort issue and also introduces the risk that when comments are anonymous people may feel able to say *anything*

## Mock up

On clicking the downvote the following would appear to allow you to select a reason for downvoting

[image]

On hovering over the score the OP of the question (and possibly everyone else) would see a bar chart of why people down voted.

## Suggested options

#### On a question

- Is confusing/unclear
- Does not show research effort
- Contains too much irrelevant information
- I disagree with the idea(meta only)
- Other / I'd rather not say

#### On an answer

- This is wrong
- This is unclear
- This is technically correct but is dangerous or bad practice
- I disagree(meta only)
- Other / I'd rather not say

## We don't tell people how to vote

Voting is entirely at the discretion of the voter and that is why I have included the `Other / I'd rather not say` option as a catch all for "the rest"

## Why not have a free form "other"

Without having to be publically accountable for their comments (or reasons) people could get very nasty. It is for this reason that Other wouldn't ask for more information

## Minimising clicks

Other would be selected by default so assuming you didn't want to give feedback this would only add 1 extra click

<sup>1</sup> I’m sorry, I forgot this was the internet. There is no stigma to saying things suck
<sup>2</sup> I say I'm proposing this, but I thought I had seen this before, I couldn't find it on search however so if so this idea needs a duplicate just for search terms

Comment: What happens if you press the "x" ?

Comment: It has come up, but I don't think in a manner that suggested a complete implementation.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd Now I'm torn with that. Either the down vote stays and it uses "other", or the down vote is cancelled (which would be consistent behaviour). But I’m not sure; any opinions on that would be appreciated

Comment: "I disagree with the idea (Meta only)" ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber You see, now I'm not hurt and sad. Ok, my dreams lie broken on the floor but at least I know you liked the format

Comment: Ewww. Dreams are really hard to clean up. Don't let those things soak into the subfloor, what *ever* you do!

Comment: -1 for requiring additional click to downvote. Votes are essential part of this network so discouraging them too much is not good. It's pretty enough that downvoting answers costs own rep, no further limitations needed. I would +1 *allowing* feedback, but *forcing it* is -1 from me.

Comment: @Mołot The allowing off a seperate buttom is nice, but I found that hard to fit into the existing user interface in a nice way.

Comment: Bonus meta reason "Insufficient red hand drawn circles"

Comment: @RichardTingle I agree it is a problem, but your solution simply appears to cost more than the benefit it brings (if it brings any, as pointed in answers below).

Comment: @Mołot In all fairness I agree with a lot of what the answers have said (I may have upvoted one). The most important thing for me was to give the best possible argument for something someone else had suggested in annother question (after experiencing the problem themselves). I tried to suggest a proposal they could support and on not finding one offered to write one myself (not to say I'm against this idea, just that I can see both sides)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thank you! I knew there was a duplicate somewhere I just couldn't find the damm thing

Comment: @RichardTingle I only remember it because I answered it once upon a time.  I think it was my first ever answer on Meta

Comment: @Servy That one on the other hand is a different solution to the same problem

Comment: @RichardTingle There are a *lot* of very similar posts related to this.  I picked one that's very close, the counter arguments against most of the very large number of "Encouraging people to explain downvotes" questions is very similar.  This is nothing new.

Comment: @Servy it's more that I specifically argue why that proposal is a bad idea within my proposal

Comment: @RichardTingle And yet the answers to that question, and its duplicate, address your proposal as well as that one.  The primary arguments against it aren't the arguments you gave, making it an appropriate duplicate target.

Comment: @Servy you say that as if answers to feature requests are definitive, ultimately a feature request duplicate should lead to a single place where all the people in favour of it can vote for it and everyone who is against it can vote against it. The answers are (even if correct) just someones opinion (with the exception of the yes/no from the devs). Psubsees duplicate achieves that

Comment: @RichardTingle When there are a few dozen related proposals on the topic, adding yet another is just annoying, and is not adding value.  When you've seen the same points posted half a dozen times over and over, it gets pretty darn definitive.  Additionally, that you didn't address the points commonly brought up in all of the very closely related posts shows a lack of research effort and a not well thought out feature request.

Comment: @Servy Having had time to have a close look at the answers on the duplicate I am now somewhat confused. The key points on that answer seem to be: “A person shouldn’t have to justify their down vote” & “You could just provide a free form box to give a reason in if they want”. All of these are either irrelevant or addressed within this post. Which of these have I failed to address? The duplicate of the 'duplicate' is slightly more relevant, eventually reaching a 0 voted answer that suggests a similar alternernative to this proposal: I believe this answer was the one I saw which led to footnote 2

Answer (score 19):

Okay, we all know that "I'd rather not say" is not for me, so here goes. The problem I have with this idea is that the feedback provided is not all that great. Perhaps something is really better than nothing, but I'm not sure it's all that much of a help.

> Is confusing/unclear

*I think it's not unclear or confusing. I wrote the question. What is confusing here? How is this unclear?*

> Contains too much irrelevant information

*What is irrelevant here? I've tried to ask a well put, detailed question. Why are you downvoting me? How can I address this?*

> This is wrong

*Wrong how? I think it's right*

> This is unclear

*Unclear how?*

Yes, you provide more information than if you'd have a downvote as it is now, but I wonder if this does not simply end up in an excuse to leave no real comments any more. Hey, we told you that 4 users think it's "confusing", now you go deal with that.

Comment: This guy sees the future... and the past too.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence.

Answer (score 7):

So, some random musings about why I don't like this idea...

First, I am generally against anonymous comments. They separate people from accountability. We have enough trouble with people acting appropriately when they *are* accountable to what they are saying. This could make things worse - in exactly one of the situations where it can most easily go downhill fast.

I'm really ambivalent about the idea of pre-packaged comments to begin with. I think they are a 'necessary evil' with the close reasons. And maybe - *maybe* - they would be helpful in some rare cases of down votes.

But has anyone checked into any stats on how many new users *even notice* they've been down voted in the first place? How many people would actually end up being *provoked* by such an anonymous comment? I can see the cries, now; "You anonymous trolls are just down voting and giving me meaningless explanations!"

---

I think if people want to explain, they should do so. And they should do so kindly, as appropriate. I don't think any canned list of comments would really be helpful and, to repeat myself, I think making them anonymous would make things worse.

Answer (score 2):

why make SO a kinder garden? If you get 1 down vote or 2 that could be someone who doesn't like you or disagrees or thinks your question/answer is poor. if you get 5 down votes that means there is something seriously wrong (*against the rules etc*) with your current question/answer which is usually followed with a hold specifying exactly what is wrong.

IMO I disagree with your idea and it would become really annoying selecting why I am down voting :/ *specially excel and vba where almost 80% of the questions deserve a downvote*

A down vote is a down vote and all you can do is live with it. If there is something seriously wrong your question gets closed / answer possibly reported to a moderator => further, it gets closed and you can see the reason why.

---

Also, if you're here for the first time and get properly down voted you may want to reconsider a few things; read the rules! how to ask/answer a question - we have plenty of help around just waiting to be seen. All the effort we have made to create the help centre can't just go to waste now.

Comment: It is something I see every day; users who are used to other kinds of internet sites who get frustrated at downvotes. Some stick around and eventually find out why, some just leave never to return - we're loosing people who could become good members of the community

Comment: I dont see much potential in people who make no effort to start off with. If someone *requests* something from us and giving us grief for not helping them because we stick to the SO rules. <= that's exactly what I mean by kinder garden

Answer (score 0):

There is already a feedback button and you can select way more options !
Let's not forget about it... :)

> [image]

Comment: but sort of exposing your identity as voter if you leaving a comment

Comment: You don't have to specify "-1 because" you simple have to give a comment (feedback) on the question. The OP won't know you are responsible for a downvote but will understand that something is wrong with the question.

Comment: @mehow I think that if we have something worth saying, we should be willing to put our name on it. I am personally *much* more likely to listen to criticism from someone not standing behind a wall of anonymity. Especially when I know they had a choice. That said, I am not sure I can up-vote this answer. But I'm not down voting it. Should there be a selection of comments for "meh"? ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber yes same here. Why are people so scared of their own opinion ?

Comment: @AndrewBarber oh yeah I do agree with you and I sign my name for anything I say here on SO and Meta. Again, going back to my answer and excel and vba case - I am not paid to leave a comment explaining what is wrong with each question. If I feel the OP has made enough effort but something is unclear then I will leave a comment - but if I see no effort (that's the 80%) I simply downvote and move on.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd Oh, I am **terrified** of my opinions. But, that's a completely different topic.

Comment: @mehow This brings me back to the point of why would I be bothered putting a comment on my downvote if they are so common on those questions about Vba and Excel ?

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd exactly, so if I dont want to leave one I just downvote (*which is a action of moderation - talking SO*) and I dont want to be forced to leave a comment.