# Convention badge clarification

Tags: support, badges, meta

The [Convention badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention) states that it is awarded for

> 10 posts with score of 2 on meta.

Meaning a user must post at least 10 posts (questions or answers) with a score of 2 or more.

If I understand that correctly, then the most recent [user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/248595/menotalk?tab=answers&sort=votes) who got the badge has only 8 answers with a score of 2 or up and 1 such question.

That makes a total of **9 qualifying posts**. So, where did that 1 other phantom post come from?

Comment: Score isn't upvotes. It is # upvotes - # downvotes.

Comment: Possibly a deleted post, but that is something interesting for a mod to find out.

Comment: About an hour ago, [this answer of theirs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220558/i-am-hater-because-of-people-not-understanding-the-voting-patterns-properly/220560#220560) was at a score of +4. Now it's been downvoted to a score of 0. So they *did* have 10 posts with a score of 2. Now they don't.

Comment: @Sumurai8: There is one post that is currently downvoted to 0, but was has 5 up and 5 downvotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember, regular badges, once awarded, are not taken away again, at least not by any normal process.

In other words, the user *at some point* met the criteria. But if a post has since been deleted or downvoted, the criteria are perhaps no longer met but the badge is still earned.

In particular, because the badge was [awarded only an hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention?userid=3177651) I strongly suspect that [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220558/i-am-hater-because-of-people-not-understanding-the-voting-patterns-properly/220560#220560) may have reached a score of +2 before being downvoted again to its current score of 0. It currently has 5 upvotes and 5 downvotes.

Update: [animuson confirms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220582/clarification-on-the-convention-badge/220583#comment715208_220582) that that specific post made it to +4 before being downvoted again. At the the time the badge was awarded, all criteria had been met.

<sup><sub>Note that 'score' is the displayed post score, which is upvotes minus downvotes; the badge is not awarded just for upvotes alone.</sub></sup>

Comment: @Simon_eQ: Why does it mean that? Those votes were not all cast at the same time. It could have accumulated 3 or 4 upvotes before any downvotes were cast, for example, the badge awarded, then **hours later** have received downvotes to push it below +2 again.

Comment: @Simon_eQ: No, badges are awarded in batches, where a batch job checks if criteria are *currently* met. When that badge was awarded, the criteria were there to earn the badge.

Answer (score 5):

Except in extreme cases, badges aren't rescinded once awarded. The most likely explanation is that one of the upvotes on one of that user's posts was removed (unupvote, voter account removed), the post itself was removed, or a post received a downvote *after* the badge had been awarded.