# What is the main aim of us being here?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

In one [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198262/176427) from a respected member of community I have read:

> the single most important way to give back to the site is by voting.

I would not react to merely one of many point of views I do not agree with, but here I have views opposite to the author of the post and it seems, many other people, for I don't see any negative comments there. I know that here are many people who are very nice and helpful, but are they in the majority?

For me the main aim of being here is to get and take information, to help people and get help in this way.

So, the main activities on SO for me are:

1. Answering
2. Questioning
3. Editing
4. Commenting
5. And only somewhere here goes checking, voting, flagging and voting for close/open.

Yes, the voting helps the later reader to evaluate the comparable quality of the answers, but it is not too clever to believe only these numbers. The interested person should read all answers, discussion, compare and analyze the content of post, look at linked pages and so on. I would never headlessly use an advice simply because it was voted for by somebody else.

I also agree, that here on Meta the voting is more important, and could reach the 4<sup>th</sup> place, before editing, but still, new ideas and their textual analysis cost much more than our votes for and against them.

**Edit:**

As Jeff Attwood said in [The Gamification](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/10/the-gamification.html)

"a programmer in Brazil learning alongside a programmer in New Jersey. Not because they're friends – but because they both love programming."

**Not because they love votes, notice it!**

I am very interested in the community view on this problem.

**Edit2**

1. As Jon Skeet said, I have mixed the love to vote with the votes mongering. Sorry for that.
2. If we'll divide those two, it is obvious, that there are people here, that love to vote more and people who love to answer more. Both types are useful and important for the life of the site.

But for me voting will never be more important, sorry.

Comment: *I very interested in the community view on this problem.* What problem?

Comment: @juergend I see it as a problem. If you do not, it is info, too.

Comment: "What is the main aim of us being here?" Slacking off during work hours? Oh no, wait, that's the reason, not the aim. Ahm, providing high quality, free content for everyone, and voting happens to be the mechanism that allows high-quality content to float to the top of the list (and also drowns low-quality content in the Deep Waters of Downvotes).

Comment: You are missing a very important part of that phrase... `give back`.  You find the solutions to your problems so you vote up or vote down based on what you think was helpful.  Not everyone can write a good answer, and not everyone can ask a good question, commenting/editing is important only for moderation.  Voting is what drives the site

Comment: @psubsee2003 I am not telling that it is not important. The engine in the car is very important, too. But even without it the cart was pulled by horses. And even without any cart I can walk. You are mixing the mean and the aim. And the mean is not THE REASON

Comment: So what do you think *is* the problem? It's not at all clear from your question.

Comment: "the main aim of being here is to get and take information" - and voting is what makes it possible. It discourages posting bad information, and allows sorting information by usefulness an reliability.

Comment: @JonSkeet According to the reactions, people are mixing an instrument with the target and say that the instrument is more important. If that would be correct, nobody would answer to people with rep. below 15, for example.

Comment: @Gangnus: You haven't given any evidence of that. You yourself said that something being important isn't the same as something being an aim. Voting can be the most important thing we do without being the reason to be here. What *practical problem* are you actually seeing? Are you *seeing* people not answering good questions?

Comment: @Gangnus it seems to me that *you* are mixing things a bit. Nowhere in the documentation I can't see anything that says voting is a "target", or anything. It says it is a "way", so it's perfectly consistent with your view of it as an instrument, not an aim - so why are you trying to make it a problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have answered to you already: people, who are seeking for votes excessively, wouldn't answer to people with rep. below 15. You haven't answered this argument.

Comment: @Gangnus: My answer to it is "That isn't happening." If you think it is, please provide examples of *good* questions from low-rep users which are being ignored. If you can't find such examples, you have no evidence that there's a problem.

Comment: @Gangnus When I’m answering a question, I’m not only answering for OP. I’m answering for *anyone* who could stumble upon the question now or in the future. There are a lot more vote sources than just OP who—just at that time—isn’t able to vote. And if I think the question is good, then I also upvote the question; and if two others do that too, the 15 rep argument is already gone too.

Comment: @Gangnus so the reason you asked this question is because you think posts by low rep users do not get answers because the potential answers think they won't get votes?

Comment: @JonSkeet It isn't happening because here are enough people, for whom the voting is NOT the most important. I know. But I was interested in proportions.

Comment: @poke Yes, I do it, too. But that works only for popular tags, as Python. Try to do it in DocBook, where there is one visitor for an hour.

Comment: If it isn't happening, it isn't a real problem, is it? I don't see how you expect to get "proportions" in any meaningful sense.

Comment: @JonSkeet But you all are telling, what is more important for you. That is what was my question about. Thank you all very much.

Comment: @Gangnus: So you're really trying to ask a poll type of question, disguised as "I am very interested in the community view on this problem"? Doesn't sound like a good fit to me.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/10/the-gamification.html

Comment: @poke The word voting appears there only once, and as a borrowing from another site. It is all about different things.

Comment: @JonSkeet No. I am far more wicked. I wanted for you to think about this, because as I really see now, too many members of community think of votes too much.

Comment: @poke "a programmer in Brazil learning alongside a programmer in New Jersey. Not because they're friends – but because they both love programming." **Yes!!!** And not because they like votes!

Comment: @poke Thank you for the citation - an excellent argument on my side!

Comment: @Gangnus what side??? ... I'm still confused by this entire question.  Can you please try to explain what you are asking.  You bring up an answer that was addressing a very specific question about a very specific feature and have tried to spin it into something unrelated, I think.

Comment: I've seen that you've been very vocal *against downvotes* in the moderators election page. Is this the "problem"? If so, please take some time to research about the voting system it here in Meta. Up and down votes play an essential role in [se] and they are part of a *solution*, not a *problem*.

Comment: @brasofilo No. As I see it, here we are talking about another, much more wide problem. And if you are interested about that my view, please, ask a question there in the comment. I am not against downvotes or upvotes or vote at all. I love this site and I dislike the position "give me these all tablets from the greed, please"

Comment: @psubsee2003 that votes are not the most important thing on the SO. And are not our most important return, too. And for you, too, for you also voted less than got votes. so, you have to write something to be voted for

Comment: @Gangnus: You need to distinguish between votes and voting. You seem to be assuming that anyone who thinks that voting is important also thinks that *acquiring votes* is very important. They're different.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, that is correct, sorry. I have put these different things together. But when I do more return to the site - when I vote or when I put an answer? The second gets much more work and is much more useful for people on the site. Let alone people who vote almost automatically to get badges for it. Notice, we have many badges for voting support and one badge for answering support. So, most people are interested in answering, not voting. (BTW, you too, with your 28376 answers and only 15705 votes)

Comment: @Gangnus without voting your answer, even if brilliant, would be drown in the flood of stupidity and gibberish. Voting prevents that and allows your answer to reach audience. So in a way votes makes it possible for answers to matter at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet look the edit. Do you agree with the ending?

Comment: @Gangnus: Seems reasonable - but it's not clear why the question exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First and foremost, the question you linked is not an analysis of how anyone should use the site, it is simply an explanation as to why the general vote counts are displayed as part of the public profile.  I am extremely confused as to why you've decided to spin that answer into a discussion of how and why everyone uses the site.  You've basically taking what I was saying completely out of context and are trying to compare apples and oranges.

### Why you are misunderstanding the linked answer

While I do like [poke's emphasis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220722/182513), as that was a key part of that answer, you are not understanding the most important part of the sentence you quoted:

> So at the core, the single most important way to **give back** to the site is by voting.

So I think the premise on which you are asking is a misunderstanding.  That answer is not talking about the aim of the site, or even how you use the site, it is saying how you can give back to show your appreciation for the efforts of everyone involved in the site.

Asking questions and answering questions are the foundation of what the site is about, but they are not necessarily how you can give back.  Not everyone can ask a good question, or provide a good answer, but (almost) everyone can vote.

In the paragraph before the sentence you quoted, I also say:

> In the current version of the site, there are a lot of ways you can give back to the community by editing, reviewing, and other moderation tasks and what tasks you can perform is based on your privilege levels, which in turn is based on your reputation, which is based on voting.

So even if you want to look into moderation tasks as a way to give back, you still need the reputation to do it, which means encouraging users to vote.

---

### Why are we all here and why do we participate?

I'm starting to get the impression that this was your ultimate question.  Like I've suggested, the linked answer you chose was certainly a wrong approach and you've only confused the situation given the context of that post.

I don't think anyone can answer this question as it is completely opinion based.  Obviously everyone is on this site because they came to Stack Overflow to get answers at one point in time, and they stayed for various reasons, maybe because they enjoy answering questions, maybe they like reading about different questions, maybe they do enjoy the gamification, maybe they liked everything.

I am sure there are users who care too much about rep and participate only for the rewards, but given your rep will only get you one of [Pekka's handbags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUpgr.png) and in some rare cases maybe a job offer, that is not really a reason to participate for most users (I would image).  At least I don't participate for the rep.  If I did, my rep on SO would be a lot higher as I would be asking and answering a lot more.  I just enjoy participating as I do now.

Comment: I agree with the first part of your post, but I can't agree with the last paragraph - there are thousands sites that are popular and have no voting system, and there are sites with voting system that are weak and uninteresting. When SO started, voting system was very important to win the first auditory from already existent sites, but now the sheer size of the site makes it important. And when another site will coma as the next winner, it will win by something else, not by voting system. And if the SO would depend on voting system only, it will easily lose.

Comment: @Gangnus Its not "depending on" just voting; theres high quality questions and answers. Remember the quote was regarding "giving back"

Comment: You can't possibly disagree with the entire last paragraph as the first sentence there is a statement of fact.  The 2nd sentence of the last paragraph is only my opinion, but I believe that to be the case.  The site may still exist in some form, but it would not nearly be the site that exists today.

Comment: @psubsee2003, ok, sorry, last sentence

Comment: @RichardTingle I think, that helping somebody with editing or inventing an answer for a difficult question I am returning MUCH more than just voting.

Comment: @Gangnus I am genuinely what the premise of this question is.  You seem to be very focused on ranking what is important in how you use the site.  If that's all you are trying to do, then you are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Read the edit of the question. Do you agree now? And I am sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: As for your last edit - yes. I was only astonished to read that somebody (you) is here for voting. So I raised the question.

Comment: That once again seems to be a misrepresentation of what was said.

Comment: @Gangnus yes, your last edit does make it clear there was a misunderstanding on how you were interpreting the response which is why I was assuming from the beginning.

Answer (score 7):

You are missing an important part in that quote (emphasis mine):

> So at the core, the single most important way to give back to the site is by voting. **Voting is what drives the culture of the site. It provides the basis for reputation** (which on its own, is a metric many use to measure themselves), and also provides the foundation for the moderation tasks you can perform.

Without voting, the whole gaming aspect of the site would disappear. Yes, there are surely a fair amount of people who don’t care about reputation and would continue answering anyway, but for many it is a substantial part of the system—even it it’s just happening in the background, ultimately, reputation is what drives most users to contribute.

And without voting, none of that would exist. It is important to appreciate the effort people take to contribute answers to the site. And votes are the only thing that really work from any participant.

And of course there is the other aspect, that voting is a selection process. The community uses it to make good questions and answers stand out, or to let bad ones disappear with downvotes.

Voting does not hurt, but it is an important part in driving the quality. So please vote more!

Comment: I am not telling that it is not important. The engine in the car is very important, too. But even without it the cart was pulled by horses. And even without any cart I can walk. You are mixing the mean and the aim. And the mean is not THE REASON

Comment: What you are explaining, merely tell that voting is an excellent instrument, maybe the most important here. But it is merely instrument.

Comment: Yes, and isn’t that enough to make it valuable? — *“without any cart I can walk”* – Without people answering, editing, commenting, you could still ask questions. Does that help you? No. It’s the complete package that makes something, not individual parts.

Comment: "Without people answering, editing, commenting".. It is YOU who say that answering is less important than voting, not me. Try to discuss honestly.

Comment: No, I’m not ranking anything. I say that *all parts* are important to the system. It was you who said you could do without less important parts—I say the opposite: All parts are important, and it wouldn’t work without any of them.

Comment: I think the vote is becoming each time more important, because this is a good way for developers shows your skills to the market. The questions and answer that you are involved says a lot about you and this can be a good vitrine for anyone. Now we have projects like carrier 2.0 which makes your profile and reputation much more important. That's another view point we should analyse too. But I think Gangnus made a good question. +1!