# What if someone is voting me down or up continuously?

Tags: discussion

If someone is voting me down or up continuously then what sort of action is taken against him/her?

Or can I vote some every time? I don't think that such a good application like Stack Overflow has kept this point in mind.

Comment: They may be downvoting you for misuse of code blocks.

Comment: No I just wnt to know that if some does this with me then what this application could do I want to know about the rules which are defined in stackoverflow for this king of intentional offence

Comment: It's a royal pain for sure, but if you're courting some joker who king hits you constantly there are some behind the scene rules that are checked. Unless you have a fan that doesn't care jack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Vote Fraud and You](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) on the SO blog, and search for the term [vote fraud](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vote+fraud) here on meta.

Answer (score 7):

Rule #1: You don't complain about downvoting.
Rule #2: See Rule #1.

Comment: Rule #3: [Don't feature-request anonymous comments for donwvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54493/provide-optional-anonymous-reasoning-field-for-down-votes-closed). Or [forced comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2263/require-comments-on-downvotes).

Answer (score 2):

I looked at your profile on SO and you have asked 5 questions. 2 of them had one up vote each and none of them had a down vote.

You have answered one question.  This had on up vote and zero down votes.

Maybe you could clarify what you are talking about?