# Got my reputation down by -1, when I downvoted an answer

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

In this recent post: - [algorithm for maintaining a stack in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634574/algorithm-for-maintaining-a-stack-in-java/12634675#12634675)

I downvoted on member's answer, but then I saw that, my reputation was decreased by 1..

Here's my Reputation Change:  -

> -1     **10 mins ago**    downvoted   **algorithm for maintaining a stack in java**

Why this happened?

Comment: Sorry.. I saw the FAQ now that we get out reputation reduced by 1, if we downvote another answer.. didn't noticed it before..

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50030/canned-reasons-for-up-down-vote-w-example-of-how-it-would-work

Comment: [why so much downvotes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From privileges page of vote-down](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down)

> **What happens when I vote down?**
>
> When you vote down, you are nudging that content "down" the page, so
>   it will be seen by fewer people. **Voting down answers is not something
>   we want you to take lightly, so it is not free.**
>
> - Downvotes remove 2 reputation from the post owner.
> - **Downvotes on answers remove 1 reputation from you, the voter.**

So you will have to pay 1 reputation to down-vote the answer.