# Edited After Close view in 10k tools

Tags: feature-request, recently-closed

As highlighted in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56724/too-many-questions-being-closed/) question, users who edit after closing have a very hard time getting the attention necessary to reopen.

On Meta the general consensus is this

- Bad questions **will** be closed. Immediately.
- Duplicates of closed questions **will** be closed. Inevitably.
- Questions on Meta about those questions **will** be closed. Indubitably. *

<sub>* That one isn't quite true. But I needed a third for my alliteration.</sub>

Obviously, we don't want to do anything intrusive for everyday users that suggests they go about re-reading closed posts. They were closed for a reason, and we can't just assume that they've magically gotten better.

**However**, the 10k users have tools already that highlight information that already exists. The tools are there just to make it easier for them to spot items that might need attention. This is why I suggest that they get an additional link.

"Questions Edited After Closing"

That way, the 10k users could (if they choose) go through the list and vote to reopen if they feel it necessary. Obviously, this would then bump the question to the "closed" list under the 'votes to reopen' tag. But the hardest part for a user trying to get their question reopened is *attention* and this is another (completely non-intrusive) way for them to get it.

**EDIT**:
For those who would prefer a notification based solution, see [this proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56849/notify-on-edit-of-a-closed-question)

Comment: +1 for the alliteration ;)

Comment: It sounds like a good idea. Its usefulness is limitted to when a question actually needs an edit to be reopened, though, and I wonder how useful it'll be compared to the present ability to see questions that already have reopen votes (many of which can be inspired by an edit).

Comment: I was not explicitly referring to meta, this issue arises especially on SOFU and will probably increase with SE-2.0

Comment: @Tobias My answer is not concerned only with Meta. *Any* questions which are edited after closing would be on the list.

Comment: @devinb: sorry, I read meta in the third point and somehow assumed more then there is...

Comment: +1 from me.  I like both ideas, but being unfamiliar with the mysterious 10k tools wasnt aware this was viable. Seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the logical place to start looking for reopen votes after edit is with the people who voted to close in the first place. Why not notify them, 10K or not?

I use 'notify' in a fairly abstract sense. It doesn't have to be bar-at-the-top. It could just be a 'tab' when you click on your name.

Comment: There is a notification based [solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56849/notify-on-edit-of-a-closed-question). The reasons why I don't feel that is a strong solution has already been posted [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56849/notify-on-edit-of-a-closed-question/56878#56878).

Comment: I like this better, the downside being that it breaks the consistency and simplicity of the ui. That is, the new tab is completely unlike the other tabs, and it would not make all that much sense. That is why I suggested 10k, not because it is a magical number, but because the UI of the 10k tools already supports this addition.