# Dog-piling of close votes is a real problem

Tags: discussion, edits, community, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“not a real question” close trigger happy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80025/not-a-real-question-close-trigger-happy)
>   [Aggressive closing of questions suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155469/aggressive-closing-of-questions-suggestion)

Consider this question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14262913/revisions

As originally asked, it was not that great of a question, but legitimate. I have a function in JavaScript, and I want to convert it to ColdFusion. How do I do that?

I spoke with [Al Everett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21960/al-everett), the first to vote to close the question, and he originally cast his close vote because of the low-quality way in which the question was asked. He then changed his mind and tried to edit the question into something answerable, and answer it. (If he could have rescinded his close vote, he would have.) His answer garnered 9 upvotes as of this writing (which is a lot for questions tagged CF), but still 4 other people found it worth closing as "not a real question."

Al has significant history in the ColdFusion tag -- [it's his highest rated tag at 298 points currently](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21960/al-everett?tab=tags&sort=votes).

Then 4 more people, none of whom have any experience in the ColdFusion tag, decided to vote to close.

Note how ColdFusion doesn't show up in any of their tags, even once. Clearly this was an actual question. How do I get from point A to point B? It may not have been well asked, but it is about as clear and concrete as you can get.

It appears as though there's dog-piling going on here. Someone is watching a feed of questions that have been voted against and rallies the troops to shut it down, regardless of whether or not it's a legitimate question.

As I commented on the original question:

> If I go over to cooking.SE and get enough rep from Baking questions does that make me qualified to close a question about Chili recipes as "not a real question"? It's very possible that chili cooks have their own vernacular that bakers don't understand.

Comment: Are you suggesting anything?

Comment: I'm suggesting that it's a big problem that the smart minds behind SO should consider addressing. Does every bug report have to come with a patch, now?

Comment: Isn't this more of a `discussion` than `support`?

Comment: Possibly! TBH I'm not a heavy Meta user. When I started drafting this post the question was still (unjustly) closed. It has since been re-opened via community votes; but only by loudly complaining on twitter to get the attention of a few kindred spirits who are equally displeased with this type of behavior on Stack Overflow. The root cause is abuse of power.

Comment: It's re-opened now - that seems like the proper outcome to me. How would you have preferred this to play out?

Comment: @Shog9: Whether or not it's true, the above comment indicates it took extra effort on Twitter to get the question reopened. Is that the preferred protocol?

Comment: I would have preferred not having to complain about it for hours on twitter, commiserating with peers that agreed, to get it reopened. It should never have been closed in the first place, because the people that voted to close were not qualified in the question's primary topic: ColdFusion.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: No, but then voting to close when you can edit isn't really preferred either. That said: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes

Comment: @AdamTuttle - "Abuse of power"? That seems a bit dramatic; you seem to be attributing malice where it could simply be negligence/carelessness. Negligent close votes happen, but I don't think it's an epidemic.

Comment: How is it accidental? You have to go through a menu. There's no way you could trip, fall, and accidentally vote to close. People voted to close because they didn't understand and/or didn't care to improve. Just because you don't have the energy or motivation to improve a question doesn't make it a question that should be closed.

Comment: @Adam: no, but if *no one* has the energy or motivation to improve a question it might well be a question that should be closed.

Comment: It was edited prior to closing, as far as I can tell from my brief discussion with Al (as discussed in the OP); so the others voted to close after the question was edited and answered, simply because there were already other close votes. Hive mentality.

Comment: Have you considered that you might have asked this in a more constructive manner rather than throwing around accusations? As the question stands I would probably downvote and maybe vote to close. It's basically asks "please re-code this for me". I don't need domain knowledge in order to see this and I don't agree that this is a "good" question.

Comment: @ben I agree that it's not a great question, but I believe it's within the bounds of what's appropriate for the site. The question was closed as "not a real question" -- not "off topic" or anything else. It was very easily distinguishable as a "real" question. If SO had any way for me to reach out to the people that voted to close and talk to them directly about it, I would have. Short of cyberstalking them to find email addresses or contact info from their personal sites, I've got no recourse but to come here. Sorry if it feels like an attack -- their close votes could be viewed the same way.

Comment: It is so cute seeing all the StackUnderlings supporting the StackOverlords. Shows me the assimilation is nearly complete.

Comment: Hang around a but @scott, you'll see a number of disagreements with the overlords; however, occasionally people agree. You've entered one thread and found some. Judging by the closing and reopening of the question you.can see there are people out there with differing views.

Comment: *[waits for Godwin's Law to be invoked]*

Comment: You know who else closed questions without prior tag experience?

Comment: This was not a legitimate question. Stack Overflow is not a code writing factory. Closing code requests with zero own effort is totally standard fare and does not require knowledge of the tag.

Comment: I can't believe there's been this much discussion over a code-translation question.

Comment: `Does every bug report have to come with a patch, now?` <- No, it should come with expected behavior, which you have not provided. Instead, you have used loaded language to complain about the voting behavior of users on SO. Help us out; give us some ideas on what can be done about the problem you perceive.

Comment: @ScottStroz Keep in mind that this kind of policy isn't just set by one or two people for which everyone here is defending.  Not only is the site community moderated, but most of the guidelines are set by the community itself.  When there is general consensus that a category of questions is inappropriate, it's closed; when there's consensus that a previous close worthy topic should be in scope, the policy changes.  That's what meta is here for, to discuss borderline issues and determine what "the community consensus" is.

Comment: I saw the title and so badly wanted to upvote this, until I read the body

Comment: As @Servy said, all this has been discussed before: ["Not a real question" close trigger happy?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80025), [Strategies for improving vs. legitimate closure](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113015), [Isn't "vote to close" being used too much?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69618), [How much chance should newbie questions be given before closing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99048), [How to restrain improper NARQ votes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99537).

Comment: See also: [Properly close poorly researched questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117731), [How soon should I vote to close?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98022), [Is it acceptable to close a question without leaving a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39057), [Please think twice about closing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94698), [What grace period do you allow someone to reformat his question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125295)

Comment: also related: [Do you wait for edits before voting to close a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161872/165773) **"Let's say that there is a question asked in a bad manner... It may happen that the question gets edited... to a valid question..."**

Comment: @ScottStroz You keep writing of the StackOverlords, and I keep not figuring out who you mean. Do you mean everybody with `>= n` rep (in that case, what's `n`?), or do you mean moderators, or whom?

Comment: @DanielFischer I am referring to the people who feel their moderator status on SO makes them somehow superior to others. Maybe that is what it is intended to be (as evidenced by some of the replies here). To me, the douche ratio is extremely high in the StackOverlord ranks (and even among the StackUnderlings). The response to this thread sends a very clear message; 'Do not question the StackOverlords, or ye shall feel our wrath'. A friend put it a great way - 'SO is great for readers, but a pain in the ass for contributors.'

Comment: @ScottStroz "moderator status" as in diamond mod, or as in `>= 10k`? As for your friend's quote, I can't agree, I haven't found contributing a pain in any body part.

Comment: @DanielFischer it has less to do with 'rep' and more to do with attitude and actions. In my experience, many SO 'moderators', regardless of how much 'rep' they have, have an attitude that they are superior to others simply because they have the time to answer a lot of questions. As someone who uses SO a lot in terms of needs solutions to problems, I love the site. As someone who sees the inconsistency of how the 'rules' are applied, it sometimes feels like I am in high school again and all the 'moderators' are the 'cool kids' putting everyone else down.

Comment: @ScottStroz Nonsense. Not a single user on the site is powerless. You can flag for moderator attention if you see something bad happen. If you have the privilege, you can vote to reopen unfairly or mistakenly closed questions. If you don't understand the motivations behind closure, you can come to Meta and ask. See an inconsistency in the application of the rules and you would like to discuss it? Ask us here. And if users are rude or offensive, that's a nono. Flag flag flag. But don't use your whiny "Overlords" nonsense. It won't help you get your point across and is inaccurate.

Comment: @Bart - In my experience, it is an accurate description, and it does get my point across. If StackOverlord offends you, you are likely a StackOverlord. StackOverflow has become the embodiment of 'The Soup Nazi'. If you do not precisely follow outrageously strict guidelines....No SO for You!!!

Comment: @scott I should have known my comment was a wasted effort at something constructive. Suit yourself.

Comment: @Bart - Contructive? Adam Tuttle tried what you described and he got lambasted by the StackOverlords and their minions. This thread has done nothing but support my feelings about those who moderate SO. A great idea, ruined by the sense of superiority of those who measure their worth by how much 'rep' they have.

Answer (score 34):

That question should have been closed, in my opinion, and it should have stayed closed.  It's asking us to translate code without showing us what was tried so far.  The edit doesn't improve upon that.  The close voters don't need to have any experience in ColdFusion to see that.

Comment: If you don't have experience with any of the tags why would you be browsing that question?

Comment: @MattBusche: Moderation *does not require* experience in the tags.  It doesn't take an expert to figure out that the OP is asking for a language translation.

Comment: @MattBusche One person did have experience in CF, and the others probably saw it through the review queue after the first vote was cast.

Comment: So what you're saying is that newbies are not welcome?

Comment: How does *"without showing us what was tried so far"* translate to *"you're saying is that newbies are not welcome"*, @Adam?

Comment: @AdamTuttle I don't know how you translated my answer into that.  We're not a code translation service.  If the OP showed what they tried, that question would be fine.

Comment: @AdamTuttle: After The Great "What Stack Overflow Is Not" Wars of 2012, and the ensuing Summer Of Love, I'm more inclined to simply let the close reasons speak for themselves.

Comment: New users [are shown the EULA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), @Adam.

Comment: I think the problem that's being missed here is that people are very trigger-happy on the "close" option.  Some people aren't very articulate (or, hey: *clever*), so their questions will not come across too well. Al tidied this question up, but we could have also give in the original person a *chance* to come back and improve their question with more info. Voting to close in these cases is not constructive; clarifying what additional info is needed to make the question a good one *is* constructive. If the original person abandons it: fine, close it. But give them a chance.

Comment: @AdamCameron: They get that chance when their question is closed.  Closure merely stops answering, giving the OP time to clarify and clean up their question so that it can be reopened.

Comment: Another consideration is that four of the five people who voted to close could not possibly have offered any help here, so I seriously question how it is they're allowed to participate in such a negative way on a topic they know nothing about. How about people in the community for which the question is asked get to decide how to guide people into asking a good question, and getting a good answer. The answer to the question was, incidentally, a very good one, and the ANSWER is worth having around, even if the question is not.

Comment: @AdamCameron The help they provide is keeping the site clean and free of poor questions.

Comment: I would love to know what 'not a real question' means. If someone makes an interrogatory statement, to which a valid response can be made, isn't that a 'real' question?

Comment: Doing someone else's work is certainly "not constructive".

Comment: @RobertHarvey, the gap between first close vote and the question being closed could at best be measured in hours (it seemed to only be a couple). Bear in mind people use S/O from all around the world, so that window is inappropriate if there's supposed to be a window to update the question: they might be asleep or at home, etc. Equally, unlike some people around here, the person asking the Q might no reside in S/O, so might not see the situation for a coupla days.

Comment: @ScottStroz: *"This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."*

Comment: I think the root of the problem here is that it's easier to vote to close than it is to say, "hey, you didn't tell us what you tried or why you're stuck. maybe check out the faq and this how-to-ask page..." Closing is seen as an end-all-be-all position, and the OP probably gives up on it at that point rather than taking it as an indication that they could improve the question and get it reopened. Thinking back to the early podcasts with Joel and Jeff, wasn't one of the driving forces the desire to make the intended behavior the easiest? People close-vote instead because that's easier.

Comment: @AdamCameron: Nothing prevents a closed question from being improved by the OP.

Comment: ... except the fact that it being closed means people stop paying attention to it. Nobody _can_ answer a closed question, so nobody (or, barely anyone) looks at them.

Comment: ... thus why an OP would feel like they've been kicked out. A sense of, "My question wasn't good enough, so they slammed the door in my face." -- Perhaps there's a middle ground that should be found, where the question is put into "time-out" and answers aren't allowed, but it's not considered "closed", and people can work with the OP via comments and chat to help them improve the question to an answerable, appropriate format.

Comment: @AdamTuttle: `Nobody can answer a closed question, so nobody (or, barely anyone) looks at them.` -- A fine motivator for people getting their questions right *the first time.*

Comment: @AdamTuttle - and when the question is edited, it gets bumped back to the top of the Active queue, where people can see it again, and decide if it's worth re-opening.

Comment: @AdamTuttle `the question is put into "time-out" and answers aren't allowed` That's exactly what closed means.  It's not deleted.  All of what you just said is allowed when a question is closed.

Comment: @AdamTuttle: I'm saying that you're misunderstanding closing.  The two-day period between the time a question gets closed and it becomes eligible for deletion gives the OP time for the question to be improved so that it can be reopened.  If bad questions can be answered anyway, what motivation is there for making your questions any better?

Comment: "Closed" sounds fairly final. It sounds like the decision of the supreme court. If that's what its intended use is, I would vote we simply change the name from "closed" to something else -- "Needs Improvement" would work for me.

Comment: @Robert Harvey - and I do not think the question, even in its original, unedited format, meets any of those. It was a pretty specific question, not overly vague. Maybe there should be a new reason for closing questions: 'StackOverlord has their panties in a bunch'. That would be more easily understood.

Comment: A little new user education about how the system really works goes a long way, @AdamTuttle.  Some questions cannot be redeemed; the close reason for "Not a Real Question" already states that the question can be reopened if it is improved.

Comment: @ScottStroz: Nice try, but maybe constructive discussion works better here, hm?

Comment: @AdamTuttle The close reason already says " For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, [see the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close)."

Comment: @RobertHarvey so you think the best way to educate new users about the system is by closing their questions when a StackOverlord deems the question unworthy?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Agreed! Maybe the change should be, then, that when a question is closed, the OP (and everyone else?) sees, in addition to the current info box, a "You can fix this and get your question reopened! Here's how..." box.

Comment: @AdamTuttle: It already says that in the close reasons.  Look at them carefully.

Comment: @BilltheLizard See, that part of the message is so small and insignificant that I forgot it was there. A bigger deal should be made of that. If the intention is for people to improve their questions so that they can be reopened, then the lead is definitely being buried here.

Comment: @ScottStroz: Yes.  What they need to do next is described in detail in the close reason.

Comment: @RobertHarvey right, they need to make it a 'real' question.....

Comment: @ScottStroz: *It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.*

Comment: Look, I am not here simply to complain, I see a real problem and I am trying to constructively work on finding a good solution. I think that an alteration to the close reason box could go a long way to getting OP's, especially newbies to SO, to follow through and improve their questions. But I also think that it's too easy to vote to close something when there are no constructive comments; and often the OP doesn't get a chance to see the comments/votes before the close happens. Then s/he falls victim to the poorly designed close reason box, burying the lead of "here's how you can fix your Q"

Comment: @RobertHarvey Anyone who seriously cannot tell what is being asked in that question is either a moron or being purposely obtuse. Was it poorly worded? Sure, but even in its original format it is easy to tell what is being asked.

Comment: Maybe an automated comment on close votes that includes the potential close reason: "There has been at least 1 vote to close this question as 'not a real question'. Please review the FAQ and our how-to-ask guidelines to make your question more answerable and valuable to the community." The problem is that a close vote **feels like** a door slamming in your face, whether or not it's supposed to.

Comment: @ScottStroz: It's boilerplate verbiage.  We can't expect it to be a glove fit for every possible question variant that still needs to be closed anyway.  Sure, some questions you can tell what is being asked, but they can still be *ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and not reasonably answerable in their current form.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey I can understand that, I just don't think this question..errr....in question....fits ANY of those things. Was not ambiguous, was not vague, was not incomplete (poorly worded, yes, but not incomplete), was not overly broad nor rhetorical and given the fact that it was answered by a StackOverlord, it most certainly was reasonably answerable.

Comment: @AdamTuttle: What you might be missing here is that there is a substantial percentage of new folks who want to use the site any way they want, and are *not interested in being educated about how SE works.*  There are significant frictional barriers erected for those folks; an automated low-quality filter, question bans, and the like.  *There's no need to make it any easier for them.* For those questions that are borderline (like the one we're discussing), reopen votes exist as a safety valve, but the community still has a say in what they consider on-topic or not.

Comment: To put it another way, this is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything wrong with asking code translation questions, that is a legitimate programming exercise.

Comment: When someone posts a question and it's closed the poster has two general options.  They can say, "you didn't do it my way, I'm taking the highway and leaving your complex site that demands high quality questions." or they can say, "I'll go figure out what it is that you think I did wrong and fix it so that you will be willing to answer my question/solve my problem."  For those who choose the first; let them leave, we don't *want* their low quality content.  For the latter, the system is working as intended and placing some of the burden on the asker, instead of allowing just any question.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: *I have this highly-localized code in VB.  What is the equivalent code in C#?*

Comment: @LanceRoberts It's a higher level issue than that.  The problem here is that the question was just a "gimme teh codez" question.  It listed a requirement and expected the exact code to solve it.  It doesn't matter if the requirements are in English or in some other programming language, on SO we want to see some effort demonstrated; a problem with the OP solving their problem, not just them asking us to solve the entire task they have.

Comment: @LanceRoberts So are the questions at the end of each chapter of many good programming books, but if you post the questions without showing what you've tried you can expect those to be closed as well.  Like I already said, if they had showed what they'd tried, I wouldn't have a problem with the question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey a random string generator is considered 'highly-localized'? Those are some strict guidelines.

Comment: @ScottStroz: That was just an example for Lance to chew on.  It's more than just localization; the OP asked a `canihazcodez` question, and to "prove" that he put in some effort, pasted some code from a different language.  There's no mystery why the question wasn't well-received.

Comment: I give up. I still believe there is room for improvement with this whole close thing, but I just don't have the energy to try any more. I've made my case, said what I wanted to say, and I've been thoroughly shut down; nobody seems to want to hear what I have to say. So I'm done. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AdamTuttle Welcome to the Meta gauntlet. :)  As frustrating as this process can seem, it *is* helpful to the community's health, and we do appreciate the conversation.

Comment: One could make the argument that ANY question on SO that requires code in the answer could be considered a canihazcodez question.

Comment: @ScottStroz: Which is why I'm not particularly thrilled that asking "what have you tried" has become such a habit with the SO community.  I'd much rather see a large collection of "here's how you do this particular thing" posts over the usual, "why doesn't this work" fare.

Comment: @AdamTuttle, feel free to form a feature-request and submit if you have a specific improvement you'd like to see.

Comment: @AdamTuttle In case you weren't aware, this isn't a brand new topic.  Pretty much everything in this discussion has been thoroughly discussed before.  Your complaints are not new, and some come up fairly regularly.  That doesn't mean they aren't welcome, but (among other things) it does indicate that you didn't research this issue much on meta before coming here to pick up where previous discussions left off.

Answer (score 21):

First off, this *can* be a real problem - I don't want to down-play the danger of stuff getting shut down without due consideration.

That said, I think you hit on the key problem with that particular question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163416/dog-piling-of-close-votes-is-a-real-problem#comment473197_163421):

> Then any of the 5 people that voted to close could have simply left a comment to that effect, instead of closing. [...]

Actually, there were several comments there until about an hour ago. Originally, this comment was posted:

> - "Convert this code for me" questions are generally off-topic.

This was then removed when the question was edited, but nothing was added to replace it until about four hours ago with someone's rather bitter comment, but still no one really defended the question - they just griped about the question being closed *and* answered, which frankly seems rather petty and certainly wasn't productive if the goal was to see the question re-opened.

Let's face it: the question had problems, someone identified those problems and both answered the question and did his best to fix them - but he also did not feel that the question was appropriate and voted to close it. If you disagree, voting to re-open *and stating your reason for disagreement* should have been your first step.

Griping about the people who closed the question rather than stating the merits of the question itself is unlikely to change the mind of anyone thinking about voting to close or re-open it.

Comment: I've had the question open since 9 or 10 am (US-Eastern) and never saw that comment. I'm sure you have more access than I do, but deleted comments don't really help.

Comment: Ack, I apologize - most of those comments were removed an hour ago, but the first one was removed a day ago - just before the edit was submitted.

Comment: No sweat. Thanks for clarifying. :)

Comment: "the danger of stuff getting shut down without due consideration" -> [Herd mentality closure of questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156816/165773) _"...4 other users agreed that your question wasn't a duplicate and reopened your post."_

Answer (score 10):

It's likely these close votes came from people using the ["Close Votes" review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/1316334):

It's a big list of questions that have close votes, and it shows you posts that aren't in your tags as well as ones that are. Currently it's loaded with 47,000 or so questions.

However there also exists a ["Reopen Votes" review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) with posts that have 1 or more reopen vote. I think it is very effective.

There's a lot of close votes to review, so once in a while a post will get closed when maybe it should not have, but it if gets a reopen vote it will get reviewed *fast*. I mean, just look at these numbers:

[image]

I'd say no additional action is needed.

Comment: Being below the 10k threshold myself, I wasn't aware of this feature. It seems reasonable. I think that possibly the threshold should be considered, though. 10k seems pretty high to me.

Comment: 10K seems about right to me, it ensures the reviews are all by experienced users (meaning mostly, experienced at Stack Overflow itself). "Reputation" is the only way we have currently to judge how to "trust" a user to moderate the site.

Comment: @AdamTuttle this is almost certainly why this happened. I see close votes all the time or I see inappropriate "what have you tried" comments from people that don't have a prayer of answering the question on questions that in the close queue.

Comment: I don't think that 10k is the threshold, at least not anymore.  I'm just a little over 5K, and I can see that queue

Comment: Indeed! I do have the feature, myself. It's just buried (small, cluttered) up in the header.

Comment: Ah it may be 3K even, the feature came out after I was 10K already and I can't actually find anything about it under [`/privileges`](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges). I figured it was bundled with access to [moderator tools](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: You can access the queue as soon as you have the privilage of close voting, which is at 3k.  (The old version of the queue required a higher level of rep, which may be the source of the confusion.)

Answer (score 7):

Actually everybody here is human (maybe Jon Skeet isn't). 5 people are necessary to close a question and they all need a fair amount of rep.

So I would say all possible is done and yes - sometimes a question gets closed that shouldn't have. If you see one - cast a reopen vote and leave a comment why.

Comment: I think you missed the point. 4 of the 5 StackOverlords who 'voted to close' have 0 rep in the tagged technology. I hope someday that I get 'enough rep' so I can start randomly voting to close questions based on technology I have no experience with, because it does seem like that is how its done.

Comment: You don't need rep in a particular area to see if a question should be closed. To see if a question is ok can most of the times be seen in a few seconds IMO.

Comment: I think that was @ScottStroz's point, juergen.

Comment: @AdamCameron: I detected a bit of sarcasm in Scott's point.

Comment: The comment is definitely very important, particularly after an edit + reopen vote. It explains to other users why you think the question should not be closed, and can help sway their opinion

Comment: @Scott you don't need experience in the Cold Fusion tag to determine that a code writing request is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Requests like that are off topic in *all* tags. Period.

Comment: Wouldn't any question on SO that needs code in the answer technically be be a 'code writing request'?

Comment: @Scott no. There's a huge difference between "I have this huge code, plz translate it for me" and "how do I y the z in this jQuery code?". Or "I am translating this huge code into ColdFusion, but x doesn't have an equivalent in CF. Which function should I use?"

Comment: How so? Each is asking for code on how to accomplish something.

Comment: There a a difference in: *Give me the code for my problem* and *Can you help me find the error in my code*. BTW the answer to the second request does not necessarily need to contain code.

Comment: @ScottStroz Could you please stop using "StackOverlords" instead of users? It doesn't help the discussion, and it's more keystrokes.

Comment: I unfortunately have ColdFusion experience and VB experience and COBOL experience...but I don't go out looking for those questions to answer because I'd rather not have to use them ever again. However, I have the chops necessary to vote to close something in any of those tags, even though I do not participate in them. Using someone's "experience" in a tag is a worthless metric. (QED)

Comment: @Asad - I don't view them as 'users', they are moderators, who, in my opinion, frequently abuse their 'power' as such, and more importantly, hand down judgement rather inconsistently- hence the StackOverlord monicker.

Comment: @Scott there are [12,600 "moderators" then](http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=357&tab=reputation&filter=all). Stack Overflow is a community moderated site, users closing questions is an important part of the janitorial process here... with those numbers, some inconsistency is to be expected. Also incorrect closings (which happen occasionally) can be reverted. But then, I get the feeling you're not really interested in a conversation.

Comment: Anyway, I'm interested to see whether your views will remain the same once you've built as big a track record, and helped as many people, as the users you accuse of being "elitist douchebags" here, "handing down judgements"... at the moment, all I'm seing from you is self-righteous hot air.

Answer (score -6):

I think Adam has a point in so much as he points out that the first person he communicated with had a significant history in the technology/field this question was related to.

And the people who voted to close it did not, even though maybe he could have phrased his question better and possibly uploaded some sample of what he has done so far on the topic.

Still, as another member has pointed out, maybe a comment could have been added rather than to vote to close a topic because of insufficient knowledge of the subject/technology.

@Adam...
In my experience I have found some similar views as you have, where-by there is a hive mentality but its is one of the bad sides of the internet. I guess its the modern form of bullying, but no one likes to admit to being a bully. Also with regards to what some of the other members have said, they too are right and correct within their space.

I often think about time and how easily it is wasted. I also think the best option is to lay this topic to rest and to move on and not to waste valuable time debating the pro's and con's of who is right and who is wrong.

I'm sure many people will agree that the big wheel keeps on rolling regardless of how many innocents are trampled in the act.

Comment: If you think it's wasting your valuable time to debate the value of this topic then why post an answer to the discussion of this topic?  That said, I disagree that it's wasted time.  Meta is here specifically to discuss such issues.  If you aren't interested in discussing them (constructively), then don't come to meta to begin with.

Comment: The thing is that in many many cases, subject-knowledge is completely irrelevant in evaluating the quality of a question. Without knowing the answer, you can still gather the "kind of thing" being asked, which is more than often enough to evaluate whether or not it should have been voted on to close. Subject specific knowledge is nice, but not necessarily a requirement at all.

Comment: @Servy - thats a very aggressive attitude you have. My meaning was that Adam could proabbly use his time more product fully to reesolve his issue than to argue with people who have already decided an outcome because the question does not suit them in one way or another.

Comment: @Bart - Thank you yes i appreciate thatsubject knowledge may not alwyas be relavent but didnt Adam update his question? and add whatever bit code he had? after all the website SO exists to help those who need help with their coding right?

Comment: Yes, but if and only if their question falls within the strict boundaries of an appropriate question for the site as outlined within the FAQ. And in my opinion the question does not fall within those boundaries.

Comment: @ZafKhan I disagree with your premise that the community is unwilling to have a constructive discussion on topics such as this, or that they are unwilling to change their opinions as a result of an adapting community.  Being a member for just 31 days, I can see why you wouldn't have had enough time to notice the community adapting, but I can assure you that it has; dramatically, changed over time.  Usually at the root of such changes are discussions not too unlike this one.

Comment: @ZafKhan It wasn't Adam's question btw.

Comment: Evaluating questions on their merit and topicality is the very essence of Stack Exchange.  It seems specious to dismiss that kind of activity as a time-waster.  On the other hand, posting a comment (as an answer, btw) about how the discussion is being carried out, rather than attempting to constructively advance the discussion, well...

Comment: @Servy Okay point taken in so much that YES i am a new member and maybe i havnt been a member long enough but all too often there is a bullying and hive mentality online. And one often finds if you fit dont fit the clique than your not in.

Comment: @ZafKhan So because other people elsewhere on the internet do it, it automatically means that it's a problem here?  I'm sorry, but no, that's not a valid argument.

Comment: @Asad Thank you, my mistake, I mean the author of the question is it Deetu? I'm still getting used to the layout of the website and its not my first mistake. Apologies.

Comment: @ZafKhan Hive? Clique? Bullying? Please do hang around a bit longer before you settle on an opinion of the site and its community. Community moderation is one of the main aspects of this site that keeps it at the quality it is, or even improves it.

Comment: @ZafKhan That's okay, things tend to get pretty muddled in long meta discussions like this one.