# Drain Close Queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

Preferred duplicate: [How about a "Vote not to close" option to counter the "Vote to close"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close)

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What exactly happens with the new “Do Not Close”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-new-do-not-close)

EDIT: I'm not talking about a 'Do not close button' in the review queue but a 'Do not close' before someone got the 5 close requests.

Couldn't we drain the close queue (currently around 50K posts in review) by adding a function that would allow to vote for '*don't close*' in contrast to the actual one-way-close-only mechanism?

If someone feels annoyed by a question (although it's in accordance with the FAQ)  and votes to close, someone else could think this question isn't that dump he has no chance to take countermeasures. The reversal badge has been rewarded 333 times so far and doesn't seem to do a good job in those cases.

The metrics could be 3 more close votes  (majority) than don't close votes or vice versa to make it 'eligible' for the queue otherwise the question wonn't qualify for review.

Comment: Am I missing something here? The close vote queue does  have a "Leave open" button for you to click....

Comment: There is already a button for "Leave Open".

Comment: [close votes expire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today)

Comment: can we get a `status-completed` tag?

Comment: @Bart For the review queue you're right. The thing is only a few people visit the review tool and/or have the expertise to decide about a concrete post.

Comment: Sure. Get me another 1.8K rep on SO, and I'll get right on it.

Comment: so? What are you getting at? Because that button seems to answer your question... you  might want to clarify if it doesn't

Comment: see: [What exactly happens with the new "Do not close" button?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-new-do-not-close) You seem to be complaining that the close vote review queue is _too effective_, in which case see the discussion that has already taken place today: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163416/dog-piling-of-close-votes-is-a-real-problem

Comment: When you say "Close Queue," are you referring to the review queue _named_ "Close Votes," or just the set of all questions with active close votes?

Comment: @PopularDemand I meant http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/

Comment: In that case, I don't understand your reply to Bart.

Comment: I'm in no hurry to see this queue empty. As long as there's a decent population of questions in it, the filtering options are useful and that gives folks who are inclined to use them a better chance at seeing stuff they're interested in while learning to use it.

Comment: @PopularDemand My intenion was to limit new arguable questions to be placed in the queue by introducing a dual voting before they get 5 close votes (one way).

Comment: I'm sure if I would read this in my native language I would understand why this should be closed.

Comment: The close votes on this question are for duplicates; voting not to close has been proposed more than once here on Meta. If you mean a "do not close" link on each question, see: [How about a "vote not to close" option to counter the "vote to close"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close). Given your comment about deleting your account, you may also be interested in [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/)

Comment: Please don't put requests to delete your account here. [How can I delete my account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) and [How can I delete my account on Meta but keep my SO account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153484/how-do-i-delete-my-account-on-meta-while-keeping-stack-overflow)

Comment: @John Thanks, I'm so sorry that I didn't read this post (3 years ago) a guy had the same impression and I failed to express this. Anyway the same problem exists furthermore.

Answer (score 4):

If you look over a period of time, You'll see that the Close Votes queue slowly but surely decreases in size.

I don't think that we need to include additional mechanisms to drain it faster.  you just have to be patient.

If some questions continue receiving votes to **Leave Open** than those questions will fall off the queue eventually, so they need not be closed to be removed.

Comment: `the impression that If some questions continue receiving votes to Leave Open than those questions will fall off the queue eventually` - can anyone confirm that?

Comment: @AdamRackis That's how "leave open" works - three users hit that on a question and the question is removed from the queue, and the close votes start aging immediately.

Comment: @AnnaLear Thanks, I didn't know  that votes start aging. Does this only apply to 'leave open' votes  or also in  immediate close votes where I thing the imbalance comes from.

Comment: @stacker There are some criteria that make close votes age on posts even without /review. I don't recall what it is off-hand, but it's tied to the views a question is getting over some period of time. So in principle, close votes can age away even if a question is never actually reviewed.

Comment: I believe close votes never age away before the 100th view, and then they disappear after four days, with the timer resetting whenever another close vote is cast. @AnnaLear EDIT: oh here we go, I was mostly right, see [the explanation by Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97594/131713), implemented after [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97556/close-votes-expire-too-soon-for-low-traffic-tags)