# Why is my question closed as an exact duplicate?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

I've asked a question, under this link: [Finding fastest path at additional condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184191/will-dijkstras-algorithm-work-when-there-are-more-than-1-direct-connections-in) .

It has been closed (even though I've been up-voted 5 times and the question has been verified by a 12k rep stackoverflow member). Reason of closing my question is that it is a duplicate, but it isnt. There's a very similar question but it has not been solved and it has been asked like 3 years ago.

Here's the comments from my question:

*It is an exact duplicate, but the original question has no solution - only a statement that a solutions exist elsewhere (and that 815 people at SPOJ have found one). – lserni Jan 6 at 18:30*

*It is not an exact duplicate -- the other question makes no mention at all of even the possibility that there could be two or more paths between a pair of nodes, nor the extra condition attached to hem.*

Could I get my question reopened somehow? I want to set it for a bounty with a hope of getting answered. I've been waiting for that and out of nowhere, It got closed.

Thanks.

Comment: It should be noted that up-votes should have no bearing on whether a question is a duplicate or not.

Comment: Note, upvotes don't indicate whether or not a question is on topic, a good question, or not a duplicate.  The two concepts are completely unrelated.  Also, reputation (or moderator diamond) is not an indicator that *every* moderation decision made by these users is going to be correct.  You shouldn't correlate those things together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's an exact duplicate, and there's not much help on the linked question anyway.

I reopened it.

Comment: I think it's the effekt I tried to address here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163433/drain-close-queue