# Notify users of a question they closed being edited or nominated for reopening

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, notifications, vote-to-reopen

This is brought up by a chat discussion on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

The idea being, when you Vote to Close a question (and it subsequently get's closed), you get a notification when the first Vote to Reopen is cast.

This comes up because many users (on all sites) tend to downvote a question when they VTC it, and sometimes those downvotes stick (especially on high-traffic sites like SO). It would be nice if those who VTC'd (and possibly those who downvoted) get a notification informing them that the question is now in the Reopen Queue (or, perhaps just as well, on the first edit made to it by the OP).

Obviously it would be annoying if you got a notification on each edit, or each VTR, but it could fairly simple (I assume) be done so that you only get a notification on the first of either that happens.

This could have the effect of making the user feel more welcome again, as the user immediately gets more exposure when the question *is* opened again, and they start getting either the DV's reduced, or those DV's turned into UV's.

Comment: I think rewarding users who proactively fix their questions to be on-topic (in the form of VTRs, upvotes, visibility etc.) is a great way to retain and encourage better users.

Comment: At least a partial duplicate of [Notify close voters when a closed question gets edited](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56849). If I recall correctly, I think the reopen queue was a response to declining to implement something like this.

Answer (score 19):

I think this is a great idea. I am a little worried about the number of notifications I would get as an active close voter on SO. With the dozen questions I have helped closing, this could result in an enormous amount of notifications every day.

Why not make some sort of dashboard, like the current tools dashboard for 10k users? It isn't annoying yet very powerful and easy to use. Of course, we could make the UI a little smoother, but the concept is there. Also this means there is no need for an opt-in or opt-out. If you don't want to see it, just don't open it. It just needs users to regularly visit this dashboard.

Another idea might be a badge to reward voting to reopen after the post got edited. I think I have seen it being proposed already.

Comment: I think both those ideas should go hand in hand, though I still think a hint to the original close voters (in some form) would still be effective.

Comment: Maybe you could get a message like you get when down-voting the first times: "please make sure to check the dashboard regularly "

Comment: Perhaps, I don't know that's the perfect solution, but I do think this is a great alternative to our current lack of anything.

Comment: Agree. Either way: if this gets there it doesn't matter how exactly.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to get notifications for post edits and reopenings, please use the [follow post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/51) feature. This is opt-in (no auto-follow for posts that you didn't author). We won't be implementing notifications for reopen votes/nominations at this time though - but seeing the notice for the edit will let you know that something is up.