# Notify vote-to-closers the first time the question is edited

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice if, when a user votes to close a question, they get a ping the first time it is edited, so that they can review their vote and determine if they want to keep their vote to close.

This is slightly different behavior from what was suggested here: [Notify users of a question they closed being edited or nominated for reopening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267675/notify-users-of-a-question-they-closed-being-edited-or-nominated-for-reopening)

That question suggests pinging users AFTER the question has been closed and then edited.

The intent is that, if someone fixes their question before it's closed, the original voters could come back and potentially retract their votes, keeping the original asker from having to arbitrarily ask to reopen the question.

Comment: As much as I dislike arbitrary numbers there would have to be a time limit to prevent people who edit more from going crazy.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards " they get a ping the first time it is edited", ie, you would ONLY get one ping.

Comment: Not only that was already asked, I strongly disagree with that proposal. The question is already bumped to the _active tab_ after editing, and if it was closed anyone with trusted review skills will be allowed to put a reopening vote.

Comment: The most prolific all time editors (undeleted posts) [are at 104k total](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all). Currently topping out at over [2k per month](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=month). I think you underestimate how much some people edit. I agree that something like this would be good but discouraging editors isn't the desired outcome.

Comment: @user0042 so everyone uses the active tab on the sites?  I sure don't.  maybe if the question is edited after it's closed, they get pinged and then could vote to reopen it or to leave it closed.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards the max number of times you can vtc in a day is... 25?  or something like that.  so, if they all got edited, you'd get 25 pings in a day.