# How do I know if a moderator has checked an on-hold question after an edit?

Tags: support, edits, closed-questions

If my question got put on hold and I edited my question, how do I know if the moderator checked the edited question and leaves it on hold, since it's still not amended to the extent it can fit into the scope of the site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't check whether a specific person has read the updated question.

But that isn't necessary; if you edited the question within five days after it was put on hold, it will [enter the Reopen Review Queue automatically](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256567/4751173), where other users can vote to reopen it (or leave it closed, if it's still off-topic). Note: you only have a single chance (for this automatic process<sup>*</sup>), so make your edit count!

If your question was singlehandledly closed by a ♦ moderator, and they left a comment about how to improve your question and you're certain that you followed their advice, they usually won't mind a [comment reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310869/295232) asking them politely to reconsider the question for opening. Users [don't get an automatic notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267675/295232) if a question they closed has been edited.

<sup>*</sup><sub>: with 250 reputation, you can cast reopen votes on your own question at any time, which gives it a shot in the queue regardless of whether there's an edit or not.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

If you edit an on-hold question, it's placed in the re-open queue **automatically**. Regardless of who closed it. That queue is moderated not only by moderators, but also by community-members.

So, someone will take a look at it. The reviewing system will take care of that.