# Interacting with people who voted to close your question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I think there should really be a way to interact with the close voters (maybe something like @close-voters, which automatically notifies whoever voted to close the question?). In addition to that give them have the ability to rescind their votes. (Yes, something like this has been [requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) and [denied before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close), although I can't see why.)

I know there's a vote to reopen option, but once a question gets closed it usually goes to limbo, never to be seen again so it's not really a solution.

Comment: FYI: When posting a feature-request, it's helpful to be very specific about what you want. Saying "there should be some way to do x" isn't going to elicit a response from The Management.

Comment: If one of the closers left a comment, you can always leave a comment addressed to @closer (substitute the name as you like).  That's the closest you're going to get to a personal message under the current setup, and I wouldn't want a closer approximation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This idea should not be implemented.

### Closing is done by community

One thing should be made clear, although it is 5 *specific* users who vote to close, those 5 specific users are acting as a proxy for the *entire community*. If any question had not been closed by those 5 individuals, it would have been closed by five other individuals.*

<sub>* It would be irrational to believe that the only 5 users who want to close your question all coincidentally happened to see it, unless they were ganging up maliciously, in which case, contacting them would not change their minds.</sub>

So it isn't that you necessarily need to convince those 5 users to reconsider, it is that you need to convince *any* five users to reconsider. For that reason, you'll have a much better success rate by taking your cause to Meta and pleading your case here. At Meta, you'll find users who are engaged and interesting, willing to show you where you went wrong if that is appropriate.

### Your Feature Request: Notify the *individuals*

Most users on StackOverflow are closing and then moving on. The analogy is of picking up litter and putting it in the nearest bin. You've done something good.

Once we start spamming those users with notifications, it is a *disincentive* to continue closing questions. My vote to close is not an indication that I want to engage and discuss with the OP, it is nearly the opposite, in fact. I have just explicitly shown my *disinterest* in engaging.

I have already written about this here: [Notify On Edit Of Closed Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56849/notify-on-edit-of-a-closed-question/56878#56878)

> Basically it comes down to punishment/reward. When I close a question, the reward is a cleaner more consistent site, the punishment being the possibility of someone disliking me for it. [...]
>
> Once this solution is implemented, [...] I could be notified [for] every question I've ever voted to close on. [This will cause] sending out many many notifications to people who don't necessarily care. So you've added "punishment" (that is, undesired results) to the close action.

### A Solution

I do have an alternative that does not involve notification or spam of any kind

[**"Edited *after* close" view in 10k tools**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56787/edited-after-close-view-in-10k-tools)
Read there for more details.

Comment: Of course, the closing can be done by a minority of the community.  I represent a small fraction of the SO community, or even the 3K+ rep community.  There are other high-rep users who disagree with me.  Therefore, I don't claim to represent the community, and I would feel uncomfortable doing so.  I only try to use my super-10K+ powers for good instead of evil.

Comment: @David, absolutely yes, it could be a minority which only enhances my point. When your question is closed, your best bet is to seek out *other* people who can re-open, not the people who have already made their choices.

Comment: The problem is there is no way to counter the close votes, or even for the original voters to retract them. If it's got a close vote, it can only go downhill.

Comment: On smaller SE sites, drumming up five close votes sometimes takes a couple days. In those situations, I doubt 10 close votes would even make it half the time. That is a stupid reason. Whether working for the community by proxy or not, they still used their independent judgement and opinions to vote to close. If requested, they owe at least a simple explanation. Meta is the place to do it, sure, but people don't always visit meta. Some never do, and still cast close votes all the time.

Answer (score 3):

First, ask a question on the site's meta, tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions), linking to the question in question (pun intended) and explain why you think it should be re-opened.

Then, leave a comment on the question with a brief summary of why it should be re-opened and link to the meta question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose eventually the chat system will be useful for interacting with closers, but in the meantime, can't you leave a comment on the question saying why you disagree with the close votes?

Comment: Well, I suppose most people who vote to close a question don't come back to see comments and in addition to that they can't withdraw their vote even if they wanted to.

Comment: @Null I'm not sure about most people, but I leave a question I've voted on open in a tab and check on it periodically until the voting finishes. The inability to retract close votes is a problem, but you can at least discourage people from agreeing with the initial votes. I would like that feature though, I've accidentally closed posts as off-topic/belongs elsewhere because I misunderstood the question, and was unable to change my vote after the question was edited

Answer (score -3):

Currently, there *is* a way to interact with people who cast a close vote. You @-notify them in *another* unrelated question and ask them "could you please take a look at this question (link)?"

Of course, that's an abuse of the system; and it's annoying to see spam in unrelated questions. But it gets the job done (it's very likely that the intended target will see the notification before the comment is deleted).

I don't see a way to prevent it while (1) not allowing @-notifications to close voters (2) allowing them in other cases.

That is why I agree with this feature request, and believe there should be a *better* way to contact close-voters. @-notifying them would be fine.