# Misuse of reputation

Tags: discussion, support

I have found several times that people misused their reputation in closing questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Link or it didn't happen. Seriously man...

Comment: @drachenstern [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224563/ruby-like-features-in-c-closed) and just for fun [the exact same question again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391230/are-yield-and-extension-methods-adopted-from-ruby-closed)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Too many questions being closed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56724/too-many-questions-being-closed)

Comment: No disrespect intended, but it's rare for a post to be both a feature request _and_ a bug. This post is, in fact, neither. Perhaps you should read some entries in [the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user) to find out how the site works before posting things like this.

Comment: I'm gonna go with misunderstanding the system and language barrier. Sorry mate, better luck next time. Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @drachenstern:I have already read this.My question is that within 2 or 3 minutes people closed the question.

Comment: @santosh: That's most likely because it's a bad question. Maybe if you linked the questions in question we could question the question closers' motivations but without the questions to question it's not really a question.

Comment: @26 years of Welbog:I just wanted to proved that member on stackoverflow or sister site misused there reputation.So proved

Comment: @santosh, you need to ask more specific questions like, "Does C# have a method equivalent to Ruby's yield method?"

Comment: @santosh: You have proved nothing other than that members of Meta Stack Overflow have closed a duplicate question and a pointless question. If you want to prove misuse you'll need to apply a bit more effort to your logical steps.

Comment: @santosh, "SO is a site for programming questions" is a common misperception. SO is actually a site for _specific, objective_ programming questions. There's nothing wrong with broad questions, but we are not interested in them here. Would you go to a website about dog ownership and insist on posting questions about your cat?

Comment: @Popular Demand put it perfectly. Your question is awfully unspecific, and got rightfully closed by the rules of the community here. Also, posting an identical question if the first one gets closed is very much frowned upon here

Comment: @santosh: I agree that some people close good questions for no reason.

Comment: @Linuxmint:Thanks Linuxmint,I have found several times that people closed the question within minutes.Let give chance to other people who want to reply.

Comment: @santosh: well, duh - as "politics" here is "taking care of the community", someone has to do it (lest the site devolve into questions of "what's the best X" and answers of "LOL" - refer Y.Answers).If you insist that the community is Wrong and you are Right, I can offer my sympathies, but that's about it. It feels a bit arrogant from you to just waltz in and insist that we're Doing It Wrong - the systems and policies you see here have been created and fine-tuned for good reasons, and with good results - even if it means, in this case, that you can't post subjective and argumentative questions.

Comment: On the other hand, I wish people closed questions faster. Maybe not as NARQ like what happened to yours, but [too many duplicates are getting away scot-free](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions).

Comment: I am not asking what SO question you are referring to (though that might actually help), I am asking what your question is *here*, on Meta. Is it "what should we do about it?", "should we do anything about it?", "am I imagining it?", or something else?

Comment: If a question does not belong, we should be able to close it immediately. Note that it takes 5 regular users to close a question, and even if all five of them were "misusing their reputation", it only takes another five users (or a moderator) to re-open a closed question.

Comment: It seems that have posted a word-for-word duplicate of your own question, to the same audience. Do you think that "I didn't like your previous answers, so I'll ask you again" is likely to get you better reactions than you got the last time?

Comment: @Bolt, duplicates are ok now. [Remember?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: @jjnguy: Yes, I answer some duplicates, and I don't really mind dupes of questions that otherwise aren't search-friendly, but there are some things (how to do X-common-task in Y-platform) which I'm just tired of seeing over and over again. With that said, though, are too many #!-URL questions being closed as dupes of [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380) (see the Linked section at the right side)?

Answer (score 4):

It takes 5 people to vote to close a question, which means that those 5 people all agreed that a question did not belong on the site, and closed it. I don't really see how someone is "misusing" their reputation.

Comment: It was actually 10 people, since he posted the same question twice.

Comment: *Argumentum ad populo* is illogical.