# Area51: undo close proposal vote

Tags: feature-request, area-51, closed-proposals, cancel, undo

This is easiest to explain with an example: a number of people (3) voted to close the [Quotes](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22469/quotes) proposal. Since then the objections have been answered and it is getting a clear focus.

But there is no way for people to undo their vote to close.

I suggest that this feature be added, to prevent the proposal being closed by two more people who may not take the new information into account.

*Related: [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) - but this question was posted before Area51 took off.*

Comment: @Tobiad: already noted that in question and why this is different (Area51 - new situation).

Comment: Robinson: sorry, yes. you'll see that vote fade away in two days

Comment: @Tobias - you'd get an irony badge if there was one. =:-)

Comment: It's still a duplicate because it's actually the same system. Area 51 has the same components as a regular Stack site (they forked the codebase), but they're all twisted around and such to fit the format.

Comment: @Jon - agree that the *underlying code* is similar but that's not my point - this is a **new implementation** and so deserves to be discussed again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The close-votes fade away after some days, but if it gets closed before, flag for mod attention and clarify the situation. Also, if the closers left comments you could @ask them to vote on reopening.

Comment: what do you mean, the *The close-votes fade away after some days* - does this happen automatically? How long does it take?

Comment: @Mark Robinson: good question... three or five days IIRC. But to make sure, I ask it: [How long does a vote to close last?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67585/146482)

Comment: good one, thanks. So that makes this feature request obsolete, right?

Comment: @Mark Robinson: since [ Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) is [status-declined] and this basically asks for the same I'd rather say close this one as duplicate and upvote there, maybe add a bounty if you want to increase attention. But it's unlikely to be implemented it seems...

Comment: I think this is obsolete because the votes "fade away", not because this is a duplicate.