# How long does a vote to close last?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, faq-update-request

I know it's been mentioned a few times but can't find it: after how many days will a vote to close fade away if the question does not accumulate the five total votes needed for closure?

Comment: I can't believe none of us realized this in three days, but... this is a dupe of the FAQ's [close page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question/10583#10583). The answer is four days. I'll hold off on voting to close until Jon declares his test over, though.

Comment: @Pop: The test is basically over. Strangely, given the wiki that Jeff created, it's reasonable to re-ask this question as a FAQ-update/confirmation request. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure the Privileges page has a typo for this value. There certainly are close votes here on Meta older than 2 days, so if this has been changed, it's very recent. The "old" expiry threshold was 4 days.

I've test voted-to-close this question. We'll see how long the vote hangs around.

**EDIT:** It's now been 2 days and the test vote is still around, so I'm assuming the threshold is still 4 days and there's a typo on that page.

Jeff recently said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67621/close-dialog-no-longer-shows-where-previous-migrate-close-votes-were-cast/67648#67648) (10k only), "Once those [close] votes expire or reach the threshold (2-4 days) this will never happen again" but what I think he *meant* was "Once those [close] votes expire or reach the threshold (***in*** 2-4 days) this will never happen again."

Jeff was actually the one who added that Privileges text in [revision 5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/66258/revisions) of the wiki post. Which means this isn't tied to any system setting, and therefore is most likely a typo. **Or**, some sites *do* have a 2-day threshold, just not on Meta, and revision 5 was a copy/paste job where the threshold value wasn't modified. In that case, the answer to this question is: it depends on the site, but most likely 4 days.

**EDIT:** The vote has now decayed away. I wasn't checking when exactly it disappeared, but it's somewhere between 4 and 5 days. I have updated the Privileges wiki on Meta to say 4 days. This has been the default for as long as I can remember, so if there actually is a site (beta sites?) where the threshold is different, a mod can modify the wiki on a per-site basis.

<sub>Timestamp of the comment on the question that I erased: Oct 14 at 17:34 -- I test-voted just prior to posting that.</sub>

Comment: Agreed, I have a four-day-old close vote here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917925/what-do-the-arrow-icons-in-subclipse-mean

Comment: the vote is now 5 days old and still there, so either this is a bug or the ageing has been modified without announcement. Or has been like this forever... (also @pop) Or does question activity influence the ageing in some undocumented way?

Comment: update: the vote has faded away now, so it's been about 111 hours

Answer (score 4):

From the privileges [page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) :

> Close votes age away harmlessly after 2 days if the threshold is not reached.

Comment: temporarily unaccepted until Jon Seigels test is complete

Comment: This appears to have been proven false; -1 unless it's proven right later.