# Is the Area 51 limit on closing proposals for life?

Tags: support, area-51, vote-to-close

Or will I get some votes back when the proposal is finally closed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's a per day limit, I voted to close [more](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20094/astrophysics) [than](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/19500/name-my-thingy) 12 times (not always "successful") and currently have 11 votes remaining:

[image]

Comment: Great news, I'll verify and accept your answer.

Comment: @rjstelling: provided two example links and picture, you may also be interested in the fact that unsuccessful votes to close fade away, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67585/146482).