# Moving an answer to another question

Tags: support, answers

Spotted [a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/50882) on [a Stack Oveflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117083/eclipse-pdt-sql-always-save-as), which I initially took to be a "this is a duplicate" note and so I rejected the edit and added a close vote.

The proposed edit was actually a request from the OP to move the answer to another question entirely.

Can an answer be moved to another question?

(I expected a "Cancel" option for the close vote popup - but the vote seems to be irrevocable.)

Comment: I'm sorry, but what are you asking? Also: you're not really a moderator - those types are elected or hired, and have a diamond by their name. You're a "10k user". The terms overlap, but to be clear.

Comment: I recently gained access to the "Moderator Tools" so foolishly thought I was a moderator :)

Comment: I'm asking for someone to have a quick look and perhaps fix up the mess I made - e.g. perhaps to move the answer to the other question as requested.

Comment: Yeah, I know, that causes confusion. I just call myself a "janitor".

Comment: Just for the record, not all mods are elected or hired. Some are chosen, particularly in a new site, so...

Comment: @Pear is right. Newly launched sites will get a few pro tem mods appointed until the site's first election.

Comment: @random, your edit summaries are very...oh, right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you did the right thing in rejecting the edit. The [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/50882) should have been a comment instead, since it didn't actually answer the question, but was rather commenting on the answer.

The question the answer should have been at, according to the asker, is located at [Eclipse PDT weird folder order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116721/eclipse-pdt-weird-folder-order). Not knowing anything on this subject, I don't know whether a move would be right, but I know a move probably would require the intervention of a developer, which is an unlikely action.

I suggest commenting on the answer and asking the answerer to copy-and-paste that answer to the correct question, and then delete the original answer.

We also have [some discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) about not being able to undo close votes, but the SE team isn't willing to implement this functionality.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a comment as suggested, seems like the only action really needed.

Comment: On a side note: close and reopen votes all expire after 48 hours if the question is not closed or reopened in the meantime.

Comment: @John Close and reopen votes last 96 hours, not 48.

Comment: @grace they lasted 48 at one point though right?

Comment: @John Unless it was a really long time ago, no. 48 hours is the time limit for certain flags as well as how long a closed question has before it can be deleted, but far as I know close and reopen votes have always been 4 days to age away.

Comment: @grace huh. I though for sure I had read that it was 48. oh well. thanks for clarifying.  :)