# Add an option to revoke the close vote if the question gets edited

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

If you vote to close the question, it is not possible to revoke the vote - even if the question gets edited and improved. I understand that the question can be reopened, but that requires 5 reopen votes, and that happens rarely.

It would be good to add an option to revoke the vote in certain situations. Like for example edited questions

Comment: The question will only be closed if *4 other people agree* that it should be closed. That's unlikely to happen if the problem has been fixed.