# Changing Close/Reopen Votes on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

On Stack Overflow I have enough reputation to cast close/reopen votes, now I've noticed that it's impossible to change or remove your vote, **even if the question have been edited**.

Consider the following example:

1. User asks a vague question.
2. I cast a close vote
3. User then edits the question
4. I want to remove my vote but can't.

Or a different one,

1. User asks a question which I think is a duplicate of another question
2. I cast a close vote stating that
3. User edits the question or clarifies a different situation then what I have initially precieved
4. removing (or changing to a different question) is impossible.

I know that **in theory** if the user edits, no further close votes will be cast, and the question will eventually not be closed, however that's not always the case, and it does waste my flags for nothing, which isn't very nice.

Your thoughts on that?

Comment: "I know that if the user edits, no further close votes will be cast, and the question will eventually not be closed" - alas, not necessarily the case. My perception is that close votes gather momentum and some voters quickly cast a supporting close vote without properly examining the question where that question has 2 or 3 votes already.

Comment: @raz Yes, correct, added **in theory** at my last statement. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One immediate thing you can do is either add a comment stating that you no longer think that the question should be closed and/or delete the "possible duplicate" comment.

Moderators don't have a way to clear close votes, but they can close and reopen the question straight away.

So, if you think the question has been improved and no longer warrants closing you can flag the question for moderator attention. If they agree, closing and then immediately reopening will clear the votes. As long as they remember to use "Not Constructive" (say) the question won't even get a down-vote.

Comment: It's a good fix for the symptoms, but the root of the problem is still there, it would be (imho) much better to simply have the ability to edit your votes within a reasonable time span, and when it is edited to allow vote changes again (much like up/down votes)