# Cancel our own Close vote given on Question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

I voted to this question

- [Is it possible to detect an Android device with it unique id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721607/is-it-possible-to-detect-an-Android-device-with-it-unique-id#)

But after owner of this question has given more detail for the question,it seems that I have posted wrong possible duplicate. Later on I just realized that I should cancel my close vote, so for that I have again clicked on close link but I haven't found any cancel option inside the close vote dialog box.

I hope I have made my suggestion clear to you.

In short, there should be an option for cancel our own close vote on question.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has been declined: [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

Comment: Hang around until it gets closed and vote to reopen.  If you have an overwhelming reason why it should be reopened, flag it for a mod to decide.

Comment: A few notes about this. Voting to close is a serious matter, it basically means "this guy's hopeless, pull the plug." Did you first comment and tell the OP to fix XYZ *before* it gets closed? I'm thinking 15 minutes(after warning) is a decent time frame to wait before pressing "close." Also, since it takes 5 close votes to close the post then there's no need to feel guilty - four other trusted users agreed.

Let the poster learn how to make good questions. Time is a factor here too, we want to reduce sloppy behavior. i.e, closing may serve as a good punishment..

Comment: @Adel: Closing isn't *supposed* to mean that at all, it's supposed to mean "this question is *currently* inappropriate, but it will be re-opened if improved". The idea is to prevent low-quality questions from attracting low-quality answers, so the page can more easily be improved into something nice. (I realize the reality is often somewhat different.)