# Voted to close a question and then changed my mind

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)

I just voted to close a question and few seconds later realized the question would be better of on a different stack-exchange site instead of just closing it.
I have no way to do that though, once I pressed the trigger, the question is dead!

Comment: This is by design. You can always cast a reopen vote as well, if the question does end up closed.

Comment: @PopularDemand - What's the point of reopening in order to close->off-topic->other SE site ???

Comment: @Popular Demand why would it be by design, what is the reasoning?

Comment: I dont get it why downvotes. I am missing something here?

Comment: @ItayMoav - Possibly to ensure that one takes a bit of time when voting to close instead of doing so automatically...

Comment: @ItayMoav - Yes, you are. Downvotes on meta mean disagreement. The rules are different here.

Comment: Looks like the most unpopular answer in MSO history is about to get a few more downvotes...

Comment: @Adam Rackis - If I get more down votes, I'll commit suicide

Comment: @itay - relax :-)  Click on the link above for the duplicate question, then scroll down to the lowest rated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can always flag for moderator attention.

However, since it was closed and less then 4 closers (assuming no moderators involved) did not vote to migrate to the same site (including your mistake), it is unlikely the moderators will migrate as it was a community decision to close.

You can always leave a comment suggesting to the OP to post on the appropriate SE site.