# Once Jeff Atwood left the company, who became "in charge"?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, meta, company, jeff-atwood

Now that Jeff Atwood has moved on ([see Joel's blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/farewell/), and [Jeff's own](https://blog.codinghorror.com/farewell-stack-exchange)), who succeeded him as the ultimate authority over feature requests, change requests, cross-site policy, and the like?

To be perfectly clear, I'm aiming this question at the Stack Exchange management, who will be (presumably) filling the void left by Jeff with other team members.

Comment: Well...make a `[feature-request]` and see who'll show up. ;)

Comment: +1, I'm very curious too, but his seat's more than still warm: though he opens his blog post by referring to his leaving in the present tense, Jeff's next sentence explains that he's not officially gone until the end of the month.

Comment: @Jeremy - Oops, fair point. I read the first sentence and apparently missed the "March 1st". Still, the question is still valid. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Queue CEO elections. My manifesto includes allowing multiple "@"'s, removing the Problem filter, rewarding duplicate finders and better feedback for suggested edits, deleted posts etc etc.

Comment: @Matt [If they're to replace Jeff, those would be *CTO* elections](http://stackexchange.com/about/team); Joel's the CEO.

Comment: @Jeremy: Damn the 10 minute edit period :(.

Comment: This is exactly what we're all wondering. I vote for waffles.

Comment: @Benjol I might agree with you. Do you mean [waffles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waffles) or [waffles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles)?

Comment: @Andrew Saffron-coloured waffles, of course.

Comment: Very tempted to wipe the comments and place "me" as the sole comment at the top (with all the rest to follow).

Comment: @casperOne: You **power-mad moderator.**

Comment: @casperOne That might tempt me to replace the question with an entirely new one ;)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Power mad, with too-narrowly-scoped power.  That's a problem.

Comment: @razlebe Edit wars FTW.

Comment: What's the rep requirement to self-nominate for CTO?

Comment: @Matt - what about [rescinding close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes/33949#33949)

Comment: As an erstwhile noisy [useless-feature]-requestor I must hereby tell Jeff a public "I sincerely apologize" for my naive suggestions, one of which I personally found out is a fiasco(pushing asking-users to choose a best answer, because I just asked a Q that got an annoying "PICK ME Z BEST ANSWER" as a comment.  ) I would pay for a helicopter to drop-down cargo boxes of Krispy Kreem unto you Jeff, well I mean.. like near you of course. AAAND that's all for my internets today, my quotas full, back 2 school.

Comment: Maybe we'll finally get some of the _important_ enhancements done. :)

Comment: Wrong question. We need to know who is number 6.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Because we massively overworked Jeff as a matter of corporate policy, and because he wore big clown-like shoes, it took at least three people to fill his shoes completely.

[Josh "Shog9" Heyer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9), Stack Overflow user #811, had overall responsibility for Q&A quality and community management, and became the public face of the company on meta sites. As such, he was the closest we had to an "ultimate authority" when it came to community-related decisions.

[Jarrod Dixon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon), Stack Overflow user #3, became the lead of the core development team which works on the code that runs the Stack Exchange Q&A platform.

Jarrod reported to [David Fullerton](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/146719/david-fullerton), the VP of Engineering for Stack Exchange. David's other responsibilities included the [Careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) platform, [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and the System Administration team (then led by [Kyle Brandt](https://serverfault.com/users/2561/kyle-brandt)).

None of the above employees still work for Stack Exchange today, but these were the ones who directly replaced Jeff at the time he left.

As always, it's a community, and authority derives from you, our users, even if we sometimes have to overrule you.

Comment: +1, but we're a merry band of idiots.

Comment: at least there's that

Comment: Who will be on the podcast with connection issues after March then?  Can you get waffles to call in from the prison island?

Comment: +10 for us being idiots. Don't delete my 9 sock accounts, please? (even if they only help prove the point)

Comment: Heh, I did suggest a Triumvirate to rule the republic earlier today! Although my triumvirate would have contained more yellowy exotic spices.

Comment: Quite funny how fast @David Fullerton modified his "About me" to read "VP of Engineering".

Comment: How did Jarrod wind up with a lower number than Joel?

Comment: @JonH read this, thought "hmm, I should update my About Me"...

Comment: @Farry - Joel is CEO not CTO.  He's number 4 not number 2 or 3 - who cares?

Comment: mine was the fourth account they made in the database. It's an IDENTITY column, and Jarrod and Geoff were both writing code before I got my account.

Comment: Now see, if you had used GUIDs right at the beginning then people wouldn't complain about user ordering issues.  Nothing a little jQuery can't fix, though.  But everyone should keep in mind that the community comes first as user #0.

Comment: GUIDs - then no one would be able to guess another users ID :(

Comment: @JonH: Doesn't matter, there's always this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38856/rollback-to-74f3bce8-24a5-4ebe-82ea-b5c6e2512a8a

Comment: "even if you're sometimes idiots and we have to overrule you."  Dude, you totally have that the other way around.

Comment: Cool, Shog will (continue to) be awesome I'm sure.

Comment: You should consider waffles/balpha/marc for the eastern watch :)

Comment: @AdamDavis: Community is user -1.