# Will previous badges for the same question be removed  as voting increases?

Tags: support, badges, asking-questions

I am having one doubt regarding badges. There are all 3 type of badges for votes on a question.

```
Nice question - 10
Good question - 25
Great question - 100.
```

First, the user will get the "nice question" badge and so on.

My question is, will the previous badge be removed for the same question? i.e. If a user gets the "good question" badge, then will the "nice question" badge will be removed from the user's profile?
Is this also applied for many other badges, like those for answers, views?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the badges accumulate.

For example, Joel Spolsky got the [Bronze "Nice Answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=4), the [Silver "Good Answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/24/good-answer?userid=4) and [Gold "Great Answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/25/great-answer?userid=4) badge for his [answer to the question who will be in charge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121542/168333) now that Jeff Atwood leaves StackExchange.

The same holds for the badges for questions, views, etc.

Answer (score 2):

No: getting a 100 score on a question will net you three badges. The same principle works for all the "progressive" badge groups.

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, the answer is no.

On the StackExchange sites, [you **never** lose regular badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/176533) (unless you gained them by cheating, of course). Once you earn them, they're yours. *Forever*. (Or until you stop using the sites...), but this is true for [regular badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58053/is-it-possible-to-lose-badges/120050#120050).

Instead, the [Tag badges are taken away if you don't meet the criteria anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/176533).

Comment: This is not true for tag badges, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120050/163868

Comment: I was referring to General Badges. @N.N. Added clarification and link to an official answer for Tag Badges. :)

Comment: I've got bounty-related badges on meta, without having any visible bounties. That's because a moderator intervention on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119684/what-markdown-formatting-features-are-available-for-bounty-remarks).

Answer (score 0):

No.

Comment: [See what I mean](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121782/shouldnt-each-answer-get-a-point-or-two/121784#comment323038_121784)? =)  Perhaps you are just terse, and I'm misinterpreting that as negativity.  I will quit harassing you now.

Comment: @jadarnel27: What? You were harassing me? I didn't notice...though, yes, I agree that that other answer of mine is not Gentleman-like, though, there was a reason it's CW and I didn't take the downvotes personally, I never do. It was intended as a joke on the costs of the OP, to demonstrate that the idea does not work (remind you, that answer received two upvotes before it was downvoted). If you don't like the way I'm answering/responding, you're free to downvote, comment and/or phrase your discomfort about it. Remind you, if you look at my profile you should realize I'm not intending harm.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you never intentionally cast a downvote, if you do so accidentally and then click again right away to reverse it, you still get the critic badge. (I got that badge that way on both SO and meta.)

Comment: True, but the poster asks if a Silver badge replaces a Bronze badge.