# Is this a Truly democratic place?

Tags: discussion

You should add the following to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) page as I have not found an answer there. If it is already there somewhere I apologize in advance for the oversight.

How are decisions made here?

Is there anyone who can overrule a community decision?

Comment: Mostly democratic, but when the community does something stupid it's a *good thing* to have someone that can overrule it.

Comment: And who would that be?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do

Comment: The community steers itself. Most things needs multiple members and all actions can be reversed if enough members disagree. If a dispute can't be settled among the members of the community a moderator can step in (who is part of a team of moderators) and if all fails the Community managers (those are SE employees) step in to guide the community to a viable solution.

Comment: And what if the bulk of the community disagrees with the community managers?

Comment: They all go to quora.com?

Comment: Why is democracy considered the only way decisions are made when that isn't true in life?

Comment: @random33 I never said democracy is the only way decision should be made, It is my preferred approach, in most situations. Screw democracy if it was choosing a mass genocide.

Comment: @Undo how is "stupid" defined and by whom?

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121542/

Comment: Downvoters Please explain yourself

Comment: No.  We explain nothing.

Comment: @Won't such and similar comments, together with the often observed mass-downvoting of legitimate questions that use the site in the way intented, is exactly what makes Meta Stack Exchange a very hostily place. The above question asks for an explanation, and it contains no statements you can (dis)agree with by(down)voting. So instead of mass-downvoting questions which are legitimate in principle, people could write corresponding answers adressing the content of the question, and these answers could then be voted on. This more professional attitude would largely improve the atmosphere on MSE...

Comment: @rene your Quora comment is very snarky, and it contains the unproven assumption that in conflicts between a community and stack exchange, the community is always wrong and the SE  community managers involved are always right by definition. This is not true. I learned about a case where a community manager badly interfered with a specific community repeatedly, and in another case a once rather high-level professional community got significantly watered down after brutal SE interventions.

Comment: @Dilaton yes, I leave snarky comments, that is a little bit in my genes. Your comment contains an unproven assumption as well. Let's leave it at that I disagree with the premises of the question and that anyone is free to go, do or don't what ever they like. Nobody is held hostage here. We are all humans and we all make mistakes. After these matters are addressed (either in public or privately) each and every individual can decide to actively participate or leave. Don't go on a crusade to harass me  about your point of view. I'm very well able to make my own judgments.

Comment: @dalton after you explain something *literally* thousands of times, and each and every one of those explanations are here waiting to be read, is it *we* who are rude for not explaining it one more time, or *you* for demanding it?  Is it professional to blunder into a place and think everyone else should bend to your whims? Or would professionalism demand that one takes some minimum amount of time to try and learn the culture of your hosts?  We don't ask for much, honestly.

Comment: @Won't If you have spent explaining something a thousand times it should have been clearly written in the FAQ. Please don't expect some one who is coming to the site for the first time to search through old answers(Literally thousands of them here) to find the question he is interested in. I did not find it through a quick google search either. That is a sufficient reason to ask for an answer.

Comment: Everything about SE is written on Meta.  That's the point of Meta.  It's a compilation of everything about SE.  If you want to learn about some part, search all questions, not necessarily the faq.  What isn't written is that this is a "democratic place".  In order for you to ask this question ("is it not?") then it has to be established that it IS.  You didn't do that.  I can tell, because nowhere will you find any statement that the SE network is a "democratic place".  So your question is based on the negation of an assumption.  Perhaps that was not your intended question?  Clarity helps.

Comment: @Won't Yes, Clarity helps. If I wanted to change it, I would have asked "Should this be a democratic place?". My intention behind this question was simply to get a clear picture. Second point is, whatever you wish this place to be, make it clear in the FAQ. Perhaps I should have realized, It was not because it was not written, but that requires an additional assumption on my part. You have to concede that it is difficult to find a specific answer given that Q/A has ~70,000 questions.  As, a new user to the meta, It is a natural question to ask when using the site for the first time.

Answer (score 15):

No. In the end, StackExchange is a company, so they need to make profit. They also know they need the community to achieve that. So there is a mutual dependency here: the community needs the company (for servers, support, etc) and the company needs the community.

The community has a lot of freedom when it comes to defining the boundaries of their own site. They can make 99% of the rules. But in the end, sometimes the company needs to make the decision. The glue between both worlds are the [community managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do).

They translate between the two worlds and help the community. They help to set up new sites and talk to the development team if a feature can be implemented.

Answer (score 13):

There are several democratic elements that are fundamental to the way moderation works on SE sites. Moderators are elected, and many moderation actions can be performed by regular users with a certain amount of reputation.

The direction of a site and the rules are generally determined by the community. There are some general concepts and rules that apply network-wide, but almost all of them can be overriden by the community if they chose so. Stack Exchange has the last word in everything if they want to, they own the sites and can override any decision by the community. But that doesn't actually happen very often. There are a few cases I remember where they stepped in and just made decisions, but those were generally cases where the community was divided or hadn't developed a strong opinion yet.

There are some other aspects that are decidely non-democratic, the most important one is the software itself. Stack Exchange decides over the features of the sites, and that is one part where the input of the community is limited. Feedback from the community is often influential on how certain featues are implemented, but if SE feels strongly about anything they tend to be stubborn even if the community complains about a certain feature.

There is a more fundamental way in which SE sites are democratic, they only work as long as there is a healthy community. This limits the absolute power SE has to a certain extent, if they drive away the community the site will fail eventually. The Creative Commons licence is a strongly related feature, it allows anyone to create a new site and import the content of the SE site.

SE sites are not democratic, but the community still runs many parts of them and has considerable influence over the development of the site.