# "Do not close" button in review section

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, review

I find that I sometimes click on the Do Not Close button when I meant to hit the close button. Is there anyway we can either:

1. Move the buttons so they are not so close to each other?
2. Give the ability to change the decision made on that particular
   post, so instead of automatically going to the next question, give
   the "I'm done" button as it appears for other review types. Perhaps only show this option if you do pick do not close?

I understand this can incur additional clicks, but I would rather make sure I'm doing the right thing in reviewing versus choosing the wrong option by mistake.

Comment: Part of reviewing is paying attention to the content (and to the buttons).

Comment: Yes, I agree, but there are times that I mistakenly click on the wrong button. I do make sure that I am looking over what is being reviewed. I'm not one of those guys that goes and just clicks for fun :)

Comment: We're renaming this button to "Leave Open" in the next build.. might that alleviate the problem?

Comment: I think it's UI @Emmett; I do the same thing occasionally. As the point of the queue is closing my brain expects the close button to be the nearest to the question.

Comment: I think having it renamed would help. Mentally my mind will read it different, and help avoid those unnecessary clicks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <kbd>Do Not Close</kbd> button has been renamed to <kbd>Leave Open</kbd>. This is somewhat minor, but hopefully the greater visual difference between the buttons will reduce the frequency of misclicks.

The ability to undo close votes has been a historically popular [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes), but it's [status-declined]. And misclicking "Leave Open" isn't catastrophic, since it takes 3 "Leave Open" votes to take effect. As such, I think a general policy of "read and click carefully" is sufficient for now.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this will really help folks out there. It may be minor, but is a frustration to many. Thank you again!