# Effect of "Leave Open" in review of close votes?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What exactly happens with the new “Do Not Close”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-new-do-not-close)

What happens when you click the "Leave Open" button when reviewing close votes? I expect I should already know this somewhow, but I haven't seen it. Does it count as a vote against votes-to-close?

Comment: [See this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155107/do-not-close-button-in-review-section)

Comment: I had already read where it says, "it takes 3 'Leave Open' votes to take effect." Does "take effect" mean reopen or invalid a vote-to-close? Did I miss something else?

Comment: It's explained clearly in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139836/152859). :)

Comment: Thank you. A search for "Leave Open" does not find that question, even though it is an "exact duplicate".

Comment: That's because the button's text was changed.

Comment: I understand. Maybe the exact duplicate could be edited so searches for "leave open" will find it.