# Shouldn't there be a reputation penalty if a question you closed ends up being voted for reopen?

Tags: discussion, reputation, vote-to-close, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

I see that many questions are quickly closed on questionable reasons. In some case for just pure mistakes (e.g. marked as duplicate of a different unrelated question).

Shouldn't bad closing be penalized like asking bad questions or giving bad answers is?

Comment: What about good closures which get reversed because the question has been significantly improved? (i.e. the system worked)

Comment: @bart: removing the voting for closing should also remove the penalty (like when you delete a bad question or a bad answer). Apparently my brain is not enough "meta" for this kind of discussion given that this question itself is considered terrible (I would have expected just a "no" reply instead). I'm going to delete it... sorry for asking.

Comment: Until they implement [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes), we would be punishing a lot of people for simple mistakes.

Comment: 1) You can't delete it. There's an upvoted answer. 2) you might want to read the FAQ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: for close votes submitted via [meta-tag:review] system, there should be (not yet there yet afaik) a protection from [meta-tag:review-abuse], that is, [meta-tag:review-audits] to catch the mindless _robo-clickers_ (eg I can easily imagine a _provably fake duplicate_ as such a review item). Serial abusers of close votes review should be penalized with [meta-tag:review-suspension], just like other review abusers are

Comment: This has been suggested before, though I can't find it just now. Perhaps I'll try looking at the most downvoted posts on meta...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## No.

Bad closures happen, there's no denying that. But *good* closures also happen, and we don't award close voters with reputation when they get it right. Penalizing them when they get it wrong would be extreme (and it feels a bit vindictive).

Just vote to re-open and move on.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense :-) ... good closures are the vast majority

Comment: I heartily endorse your suggestion that I get reputation for my good close votes.

Answer (score 5):

Ignoring the subjective side of the question for a moment, it would also be impossible to implement technically. One cannot determine the closure was wrong any easier that one can determine the re-opening was correct.

Answer (score 3):

Since users don't get any reputation gain when they close to vote a question, I would say no.

If you were talking of avoiding that a user who keeps to vote to close questions that are then re-opened votes to close further questions, that would make more sense, but it is not something I would see implemented.
There are questions that are rightly closed, and then re-opened because the OP put it in shape (and acceptable for the site where it has been asked); in such cases, who votes to close should not get any penalty. (This is a reason more, since there isn't any gain for the users who votes to close.) Then, when a question is closed, there are 5 users who voted to close (apart when a moderator casts a close-vote); the *responsibility* for closing a question is not of a single user, but of five users.

In the other cases where users get any *penalty*, whatever that means not being able to suggest further edits, ask further questions, or answer further questions, the *penalty* is for an act done from a single user. I would not be able to ask further questions if my questions (the ones I wrote) are down-voted, closed, or deleted.