# Voting to Close after Accidentally Voting to Leave Open

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, voting, vote-to-close

When reviewing on SO, I accidentally pushed the "Leave Open" button on a post that clearly should've been closed. I pushed the back button and saw that in the review panel my vote to keep open had been locked and it said:

> **PhpMyCoder** voted to leave open 1 minute ago

So I clicked on the question heading to go to its page and I clicked the close link on the question page and voted to close for the relevant reason. However, when I returned to the review page (and did a hard refresh) it still said:

> **PhpMyCoder** voted to leave open 2 minutes ago

Is it possible to vote to leave open and vote to close at the same time? I assume not. In which case, I'd say this is a bug because it should've updated to say:

> **OtherUser** and **PhpMyCoder** voted to close 2 minutes ago

Comment: This is a planned feature: [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/216955)

Comment: @JohnB Would that rescind also apply to the leave open votes? I think this feature would solve this problem, but currently this is a bug because you shouldn't be able to vote to keep open and to close on the same question.

Comment: Good question, I hadn't considered that. Not sure! Not a bug, though :)

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug, It's by design.

The two situations are separate types of votes. In the case of the review queue, it's a "close vote review queue vote", and the actual close vote was just a close vote. The former type decides when the post gets dequeued (I think at 5 close votes, or an excess of 2 "leave open" votes, whichever is reached first. Not sure of this.). The latter decides if the post actually gets closed.

When you vote to close in a review queue, both votes are placed -- the review vote and the close vote. However, when you vote "leave open", the corresponding review vote is placed, but not the close vote, because we don't (yet) have a "anti-close vote" outside the review queue. Neither does it lock you from closing the question (I see no need for it to do so).

Since "leave open" only casts a review queue vote and doesn't affect the actual close votes, it's perfectly OK for you to be able to cast a close vote later. And since the review history displays *only your review vote*, it won't get updated.

Since the review vote decides when a post gets dequeued, changing it the minute you cast a close vote may not be that good an idea; it may cause some problems with dequeueing.

Comment: +1 for "close vote review queue vote" Your excellent explanation makes the distinction very clear. My original intent was to undo my accidental "Leave Open." But this isn't possible correct?

Comment: "Leave open" isn't quite an "anti-close" vote even *within* the queue in that it doesn't stop (or slow) the post from being closed. Close-vote retraction won't be implemented as an "anti-close vote" either, nor will it be the same as "leave open". The best analogue would be retracting a normal (up or down) vote - it will be as if you'd never cast the vote (of course, the system still tracks retracted votes to prevent silly games, and I would expect this same behavior from close-vote retraction). The idea of a counter-vote for "close" was tossed around, but it would make closing stupid complex.

Comment: @Shog9 Wait, doesn't "leave open" contribute to dequeueing? That does prevent the post from being closed in a way. Yeah, it would make it too complex. I mentioned "anti-close vote" because that was the closest analogue I could think of in the close-vote world.

Comment: A very indirect way, yes. In much the same way that viewing a question without voting does.

Answer (score 4):

No, your action in review was Leave Open, whether it was a mistake or not. If you change your mind and cast a close vote directly on the question later, it will not (and should not) update in the review queue. You *did* vote to leave it open, and if it receives more votes to be left open then it will be removed from the queue. Actions outside of the review queue have never been tracked inside the review queue.

I've utilized this very method several times when I've changed my mind after already voting to leave it open. In that case, you might consider adding a comment to clarify why you think it should be closed so that other reviewers understand the reasoning and don't follow the same path as you.

In your case, all I can say is be more careful when clicking buttons.

Comment: +1 for the leave a comment suggestion. I'll use that and be more careful with my button clicking! However, I'm going to give the solved to Manishearth since he explained why there is a distinction between review queue votes and outside of the review queue close votes. Still a very good answer, though!