# Close vote queue bug?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

I was reviewing the close votes and while reviewing a particular question I opened the question in other tab to read in detail.

From the review queue I decided to leave the question *Open* but then in the tab where the same question was opened ***I was able to cast a close vote too***.

Is it a valid behavior? If I decide to close from review queue and then use tab to close again it says you have already close voted the question, but does not work with *Leave Open* vote

Comment: Can you give a link of that review?

Comment: A "leave open" review decision is not a close/retract/reopen vote. I don't see a bug there.

Comment: @Mat Ok I thought because I do get a +1 for leave open decision in the close votes count for review queue. So it had to matter.

Comment: Your "leave open" review contributes to taking the question out of the close vote queue (if others agree), possibly invalidating close _flags_ if that was why the post was in that queue. It doesn't remove any of the existing close _votes_.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug because **Leave Open** is not an opposite of a **Close Vote** (there is no such thing as a 'not to close' vote. First one is just a review result whereas second one is a vote. However, if you vote to close from the review queue it is equivalent to voting from the close dialog. In this case both the 'review result' and 'close vote' are same and one action marks the vote on both places (review queue and post related vote list).

Better explanation is provided here: [Voting to Close after Accidentally Voting to Leave Open](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185504/166025)