# Robo-Reviews for Primarily Opinion Based?

Tags: discussion

[An example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212829/how-to-initialize-an-arraylist-containing-intergers-from-1-to-24-in-java) of the phenomenon I've been running into recently, when working on the close-question review queue. I'm seeing lots of questions marked 'Primarily Opinion Based' with a single reviewer having marked it as such. This question, despite being bad, is clearly not an opinion-based question, nor are many of the others I've seen.

I've also been seeing a number of questions that are coming up under the 'Opinion' filter, but with no reviews on them. Is this because reviews have been rescinded? I'm not seeing these behaviors on any other filter, which is why I ask.

Is there a way to determine if there is a robot problem here? And failing that, is the opinion-based reason too broadly defined, such that it's becoming a catch-all for 'this question is horribly written'?

Comment: I suspect the latter (with no direct evidence); I'm not sure how a robot problem could exist for the _first_ close vote.  However, that seems like a very high potential catch all vote to me.

Comment: You will see things in the Close queue with no close votes if they were flagged by someone with flag privileges but not vote to close privileges. It is not specific to the reason. Close votes cannot be rescinded. (Some people wish they could be.)

Comment: Also, that question was closed and the majority chose "minimal understanding" which looks like a good reason for it. A robo reviewer would just go along with whatever someone else had said without reading or thinking, or would click Leave Open without reading or thinking, whichever is quicker, just grinding for the badge. What you appear to have spotted is just not very good voting-to-close, flagging-to-close, or reviewing. Not robo-reviewing.

Comment: Are you sure?  I have an option to 'retract close vote' on something I cast a close vote on 4 hours ago.

Comment: @KateGregory, retracting of close votes was [just implemented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) (see Jarrod's comment).

Comment: @LanceRoberts nice! I can't edit the comment and the first half is still correct, so I'll leave it as-is, but I am happy to hear we can "take it back" now if we want to.