# Retracting a close vote in the first post review queue counts as Reviewed action

Tags: discussion, support, review, vote-to-close, retracted-close-votes

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2999638) in the first post review queue.

I have read it and decided to close it but then I went and retracted my vote as I clicked the wrong close reason. Then, I realized that <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd> has faded out and the only available buttons are <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> and <kbd>Skip</kbd>.

Going back to my profile page to activity tab - it counts as Reviewed because I hit <kbd>I'm Done</kbd>.

Since I have retracted my vote I think it cancels out the vote so it makes perfect sense to still allow me to click <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd> as there really was no vote cast.

Is my assumption wrong? or is this a bug?

Note: I realize I could simply <kbd>Skip</kbd> after retracting my vote ( and I should have done that because the question IMO should be closed but I hit <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> just for testing to see what would happen <- it's called exploring not exploiting.)

Answer (score 2):

Enabled <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> looks fair because you put *real* thought and effort on both casting and [retracting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167514/165773) the close vote, and especially because this made it *impossible* for you to vote close again.

From this perspective, the fact that <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd> remains disabled looks right - because you *did* actions and especially because these actions were *irreversible*.

Worth noting how this behavior is different from up/down voting that toggles Done / No action, simply following the *reversible* (during grace period) actions of casting and retracting a vote.