# Can not close after retracting original close vote

Tags: support, retracted-close-votes

Today I closed a question as a duplicate, only to realize it should be closed as off-topic. After retracting the close vote, I could not close it as off-topic.

Is this by design? Or an accidental feature? :)

Comment: This is by design. You can vote and retract but then not vote again.

Comment: @juergend Ok. I tried to search, but couldn't find about it. Do you have a link to the explanation?

Comment: Animusons suggestion here was implemented: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167514

Comment: I'd love to see  at least what the other selected in the big "offtopic" hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by design. Once you retract your close vote, you [**can not** vote to close again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167514/187824) on that post.

Comment: ok, that question has long answers, and I didn't read that one fully

Comment: @BЈовић - Just read the **bolded** lines there. :)