# Let me modify my close vote

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

It should be possible to change the closing reason or at least remove it.

- Could remove the close vote when the user edits the post
- Could change the closing reason if need be

But the most useful thing is that you could change the question that you marked as duplicate. If I vote and say this question is a duplicate but I misread or the post was edited or I want to change it for whatever reason, I can't. Also, it will automatically put a comment of me saying that this question looks like a duplicate of `x other post` so I should be able to change the post it refers too.

Comment: You can already remove close votes.  The feature was added a few months back.  You still can't change what you're voting for though.

Comment: @Servy It's kind of a nice workaround but it takes 2 votes because I'm sure retracting one doesn't give it back to you.

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname you can't revote after you retract the vote.  It only let's you undo a close vote you mistakenly issued.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks. Never tried didn't know. Anyways, gives even more sense to my current request.

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname it's also a dupe, looking for the older post now

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thought so. Didn't find it thought. Post it here I will close it

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname I do happen to agree with you though.  This is a much needed feature as it makes closing confusing if a question is edited before it gets closed and still gets closed for the old reason instead of the new one

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes