# Auto-deleting an answer when it gets so many downvotes or so many flags

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, deleted-answers, automation

I am asking the current question because of [this answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/why-are-the-corner-pieces-referred-to-as-rooks-in-english/5527#5527). I've never ever seen an answer with so many downvotes. We are waiting for some mod to remove it, and people keep voting it down. They should, but why not delete it automatically?

It will be better for SE users not to see this garbage on the site. Auto-deleting something so it's not done manually will be better for the mods. It will be better for the poster himself; receiving more downvotes will increase his chance of at least being banned from answering on Chess.SE.

Comment: What about all those incorrect answers that show future visitors how *not* to solve a problem? These have a place and function *too*. I don't want answers to be auto-deleted *just* because they have been downvoted a lot.

Comment: Offensive content should be flagged, not deleted just because it has been downvoted.

Comment: I can't remember where, but Jeff Atwood posted an answer on a Meta SE question and had somewhere between 100 and 300 downvotes - his opinion was clearly at odds with the community's. I wouldn't want to see something like that disappear - it's not only interesting but important to see that the site founder will occasionally make unpopular decisions. I'm still coming to understand the SE community, and it's through examples of unpopular/heavily-downvoted content that I learn things about the community.

Comment: @LeoKing http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33949/169611

Comment: @Mysticial Fantastic, thank you. Did you find that by SQL query or did you happen to know the case?

Comment: @LeoKing I knew it off the top of my head. That can't be a good thing. :)

Comment: @LeoKing but he was downvoted on meta, meta is okay, it's where we give opinions, but being downoted on the main site is another thing

Comment: Even so, I think a highly downvoted comment has value as an example of what not to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the Low Quality Queue, in which a regular user can vote to delete an anser.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but any answer with zero or negative score, if flagged as low quality, and not handled by the mod within short period of time, will land in the Low Quality Queue, where it will be reviewed by regular users having enough reputation.

I think it's exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you that's a solution, yes that's kinda what I'm looking for

Answer (score 4):

Downvoting is important, but more important for deletion is flagging it. I happen to be active on that exchange and flagged it as offensive (although it is deleted, it was pretty offensive).

It was removed after I flagged it presumably from its downvotes and other flags, or because a mod looked at it right as you asked this and it was coincidence.

Either way, flagging that type of content is the best path towards getting it actioned, as a mod will be able to review it and take any appropriate action necessary. Posts with excessive flags will more than likely be reviewed first.

I think the system in its current state worked just fine here.

Comment: You were probably the sixth offensive flag. ;)

Comment: @animuson - You know what they say, sixth time is the charm :P