# Do votes achieve what SE hopes for? Is there a way to make it better?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, community-standards, downvoted-questions

[Auto-deleting an answer when it gets so many downvotes or so many flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233519/auto-deleting-an-answer-when-it-gets-so-many-downvotes-or-so-many-flags)

My question stems from the above link: it is actually a great question, it's clear and it's useful for others to understand why something is the way it is. Yet because people disagree with the conclusion that the question is trying to draw, it's getting seriously down voted. This would influence the user to delete the question when it really should be here for others to see because of the great answer it received.

Should we be educating people better on how to vote properly? Or is there another solution to this issue? I'd like to know as well if I'm completely off base here.

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Exchange! See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites. You posted a *feature request* and people are expression disagreement with that request.

Answer (score 4):

Martijn Pieters answered the question by pointing me to the FAQ:

In there it states for Meta SE, it's a little different than normal SE sites:
"Unlike normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta invites the community to discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the community itself behaves, as well as how the software itself works. On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself."

Comment: And voting doesn't always follow the tag.  If someone posts a discussion about and idea (or feature or proposed feature), you can end up with a similar voting pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Meta voting can be a little complicated when it comes to certain aspects. One of those aspects which is relevant to the linked post is when a feature-request is made.

Feature-requests are actual requests that the SE team reviews to see if they should be implemented. As a result of the implications of implementing features, questions tagged with feature-request are voted on based on the feasibility of the feature on a per user basis.

Users who disagree with a feature-request indicate their disagreement with a downvote. Users who agree with a feature-request indicate their agreement with an upvote.

As for the downvotes, I hope that user did not get discouraged as it is not meant to be directed at them so much as at the feature itself. I believe this is fairly understood by the meta community, but as a new-comer it can be a little counter-intuitive.