# Is it wrong to take someone else's answer from a comment and post it yourself?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

From the title, I imagine the obvious reaction would be "No, posting someone else's answer as your own is stealing," at least to me. But [the question I'm looking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233521/do-votes-achieve-what-se-hopes-for-is-there-a-way-to-make-it-better) at is interesting: someone left an answer as a comment, and then the OP posted that as an answer. It was clearly attributed, but even so I would have asked the person who left the comment before posting an answer, even if it was my own post. What is the etiquette here?

Comment: You're right, that's essentially the same question. Shall I close or leave it to the mercy of the dupe-hammer wielders? :P

Comment: tough call. Duplicates can be useful for redirection, and it's hard to predict how people will vote on them. The original is missing the relevant tags, so it might be easy to miss. I've suggested an edit in hope of fixing that, but people like to decline tag-only edit suggestions here. I guess there are a few ways to look at it: do you mind the possibility of downvotes (and do you think you might get some upvotes in the long run)? Do you still have a question that the other doesn't answer? Can you edit to make it less of a duplicate (maybe by emphasizing eccentricities of the specific case)?

Comment: No, I don't care about downvotes. I'll leave it to the community.