# Re-casting a close votes and close vote aging

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, voting

Close votes age as follows:

> Close votes age away harmlessly after 4 days if the threshold is not
>   reached. Each new close vote resets the timer, and close votes only
>   start expiring if the question has had 100 views.

I know that users can retract their close votes for questions ([Can we have the ability to retract a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) is status-completed).  If a user retracts a close vote on a question, can they then recast a close vote on the same question?

If so, does retracting and then immediately recasting a close vote on a question reset close vote aging?  If it does, this is a bug.

Comment: Not possible...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot re-cast a vote when you retract it.

Unless you're a mod, in which case the ability to repeatedly vote to close the same question is very intentional.

Answer (score 6):

No. Once you've cast a vote to close, your vote has been cast and you will never be able to vote to close that question again (unless you're a moderator), no matter if it ages away or gets retracted by you.

Comment: This has changed slightly: [you can now recast an aged vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/159251).